# Is there a way to define symbolic constants in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, constants

I searched if JavaScript offers a mean to define symbolic constants, but didn't find anything. Did I miss something ?

Is it a common practices to use const var instead ?

```
var const MAXIMUM_VALUE = 100;
```

Thanx.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`const` is not supported by IE, so if you want to support IE that is out of the question.

As far as I know, and the best way of doing this to keep it simple is to just have a naming convention for your constants like the ever-popular ALL UPPERCASE. There are some examples out there to force constants but they are not worth it for the most part. Alternatively, you could use a function:

```
function myConst() { return 'myValue'; }
```

This can of course still be overridden but I've seen it used.

Also see:

> - [Are there constants in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130396/are-there-constants-in-javascript)
> - [Is it possible to simulate constants in Javascript using closures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622906/is-it-possible-to-simulate-constants-in-javascript-using-closures)
> - [Javascript: final / immutable global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664829/javascript-final-immutable-global-variables)

Comment: you can still replace the myConst function.  later in the code:  myConst = function() { return 'newValue'; }

Comment: I thought const worked in IE now, but not in Opera. Is this wrong?

Comment: I know, but it'd take a deliberate amount of effort.

Comment: I couldn't find the other similar questions - even with google.

Comment: I usually do "site:stackoverflow.com <search term>" when I want to find something in this site. Google's search is soooo much better than the built-in one.

Comment: Yeah, me too, but I focused on the *symbolic*, which "Are there constants in JS" does not have.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. But you remove the var. const replaces var.

```
const MAXIMUM_VALUE = 100;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'CONSTANT_NAME', {value: CONSTANT_VALUE});

// usage
console.log(CONSTANT_NAME);
```

[`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) creates a property with the following default attributes:

- **`configurable`** true if and only if the type of this property descriptor may be changed and if the property may be deleted from the corresponding object.
  **Defaults to false.**
- **`enumerable`** true if and only if this property shows up during enumeration of the properties on the corresponding object. **Defaults to false.**
- **`writable`** true if and only if the value associated with the property may be changed with an assignment operator. **Defaults to false.**

if the "constant" is an object you might additionally want to make it immutable by freezing it. `obj =`[`Object.freeze(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze). have in mind that child-property-objects are not automatically frozen.