# Is it standard practice to use all caps for a JavaScript Namespace?

Tags: javascript

I have been using namespaces to package my JavaScript code.  In some of the examples that I have read, all caps have been used for the global name.  For example: `MYAPPLICATIONNAME.module.function`

Is using all capitals the best practice since it seperates the vars in the global namespace, or is it just more confusing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it is a good practice to use all caps to represent global variables, see: http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html

YUI is one of the example, e.g. YAHOO or YUI

Comment: Interesting, I didn't realize that was in his code conventions

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't believe so (quick [tutorial](http://www.dustindiaz.com/namespace-your-javascript/)). I would find it more confusing, personally. lowerCamelCase or UpperCamelCase is standard Java/Javascript convention.

Caps are usually used for constants. For example,

```
var MAX_LENGTH = 5;
```

**Edit:** Now that I look back at that link again, I see that the author *did* in fact use all caps in his namespace. But [some](http://michaux.ca/articles/javascript-namespacing) do [not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures). Again, I personally find it confusing and would only consider doing it if I was creating an immutable singleton. But even then, there are probably [better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130396/are-there-constants-in-javascript) [ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622906/is-it-possible-to-simulate-constants-in-javascript-using-closures).

Comment: This was my initial thought, but the book I have been reading gave the recommendation of ALL CAPS.

Comment: Interesting. What book is it, out of curiosity? EDIT: I guess I can see the logic if you are making a singleton with said namespace.

Comment: JavaScript Patterns By: Stoyan Stefanov

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing about standard practices is that you pick one and stick to it.  In some cases, the standard practice is, well, fairly standard.  Such as using all caps for constants in languages that support them.  I have never encountered a namespacing standard practice for JavaScript.

I would suggest picking one that makes the most sense to you, and sticking with it. Maybe take a look at one of your favorite JS libraries, see what they do.

Answer (score 0):

Nope that would be a preference.  Personally I use camelCase.

Answer (score 0):

I've used ALL CAP variable for constants, but not namespacing.

My experience is Java-style code formatting.