# Object.defineProperty in ES5?

Tags: javascript, ecma262, prototypal-inheritance, ecmascript-5

I'm seeing posts about a 'new' Object.create that makes enumeration configurable.  However, it relies on a Object.defineProperty method.  I can't find a cross browser implementation for this method.

Are we stuck writing for the old Object.create?  I can't write things that won't work in IE6/7.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are several things that you can't emulate from the ECMAScript 5 `Object.create` method on an ECMAScript 3 environment.

As you saw, the properties argument will give you problems since in E3-based implementations there is **no way** to change the property attributes.

The `Object.defineProperty` method as *@Raynos* mentioned, works on IE8, but **partially**, it can be used *only* in DOM elements.

Also *accessor properties* will give you problems, they could be *mimicked* with widely supported non-standard methods such as [`__defineGetter__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineGetter)/[`__defineSetter__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineSetter), but again, you *can't change the property attributes*.

Another problem aside the property descriptors, is that the `Object.create` method can accept `null` as an argument, to create an object that doesn't inherits from anything.

This can't be emulated with the [Crockford's `Object.create` shim](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html), because when the `new` operator is used with a constructor function that has a `prototype` property containing `null` -or any other non-object value-, the newly created object will inherit from `Object.prototype` anyway by default.

In some implementations -V8, Spidermonkey, Rhino, etc...- they have a setteable [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) property which could be used to set a `null` [[Prototype]], but again, that's non-standard, and for sure it will never work on IE.

I would recommend, if you want to target old browsers to don't use those features, since there is no way to make them work properly on those environments.

If you still want to use `Object.create`, without using the *properties* argument, you could, however I would recommend you to detect the things that can't be emulated.

The following would be a *safer* version of the [Crockford's `Object.create` shim](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html):

```
if (typeof Object.create != 'function') {
  (function () {
    var F = function () {};
    Object.create = function (o) {
      if (arguments.length > 1) { throw Error('Second argument not supported');}
      if (o === null) { throw Error('Cannot set a null [[Prototype]]');}
      if (typeof o != 'object') { throw TypeError('Argument must be an object');}
      F.prototype = o;
      return new F;
    };
  })();
}
```

Anyway, use it carefully.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a good defineProperty() implementation, take a look at https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim

Unfortunately, you cannot make enumeration configurable in an ES3 environment. This shim will let you call the API in either environment, but the properties will still be enumerable under ES3.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth,

[Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) works in ie8 and FF4.

This means its worthwhile to feature sniff and implement it where it is useful seeing as you would hope the upgrade from ie 6/7 to 8/9 will occur in the next few years.

Another thing to be wary of is that the dontEnum property has a bug in [JScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/ECMAScript_DontEnum_attribute#JScript_DontEnum_Bug)

You will have to work around the way you use the dontEnum property in IE.

[Edit]:

Here's documentation for [Internet explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548687%28VS.85%29.aspx) and a link to the [ES5 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf) (Page 122 , 15.2.3.6)

Comment: Thats good to know it's in IE8, I saw a glimpse what might have been an implementation.  So, my question still being is there a published implementation of defineProperty?

Comment: There is no such implementation for ie6/7 I am afraid.

Comment: @Drew: `Object.defineProperty` works *partially* IE8, you can use it only on *DOM Elements*. I've left an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830800/object-defineproperty-in-es5/3844768#3844768), which in short says: You can't. Property attributes can't be defined on ECMAScript 3-based implementations....

Comment: I didn't even notice it only works on DOM elements. Thanks for pointing that out.