# Understanding the difference between Object.create() and new SomeFunction()

Tags: javascript, prototype, object-create

I recently stumbled upon the `Object.create()` method in JavaScript, and am trying to deduce how it is different from creating a new instance of an object with `new SomeFunction()`, and when you would want to use one over the other.

Consider the following example:

```js
var test = {
  val: 1,
  func: function() {
    return this.val;
  }
};
var testA = Object.create(test);

testA.val = 2;
console.log(test.func()); // 1
console.log(testA.func()); // 2

console.log('other test');
var otherTest = function() {
  this.val = 1;
  this.func = function() {
    return this.val;
  };
};

var otherTestA = new otherTest();
var otherTestB = new otherTest();
otherTestB.val = 2;
console.log(otherTestA.val); // 1 
console.log(otherTestB.val); // 2

console.log(otherTestA.func()); // 1
console.log(otherTestB.func()); // 2
```

Notice that the same behaviour is observed in both cases.  It seems to me that the primary differences between these two scenarios are:

- The object used in `Object.create()` actually forms the prototype of the new object, whereas in the `new Function()` from the declared properties/functions do not form the prototype.
- You cannot create closures with the `Object.create()` syntax as you would with the functional syntax.  This is logical given the lexical (vs block) type scope of JavaScript.

Are the above statements correct? And am I missing something?  When would you use one over the other?

EDIT: link to jsfiddle version of above code sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rZfYL/

Comment: See also [Using “Object.create” instead of “new”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2709612/1048572)

Comment: [What is the difference between `new Object()` and object literal notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597926/) is related too, which is comparing new, create and just `{}`

Answer (score 257, accepted):

> The object used in Object.create actually forms the prototype of the new object, where as in the new Function() form the declared properties/functions do not form the prototype.

Yes, `Object.create` builds an object that inherits directly from the one passed as its first argument.

With constructor functions, the newly created object inherits from the constructor's prototype, e.g.:

```
var o = new SomeConstructor();
```

In the above example, `o` inherits directly from `SomeConstructor.prototype`.

There's a difference here, with `Object.create` you can create an object that doesn't inherit from anything, `Object.create(null);`, on the other hand, if you set `SomeConstructor.prototype = null;` the newly created object will inherit from `Object.prototype`.

> You cannot create closures with the Object.create syntax as you would with the functional syntax. This is logical given the lexical (vs block) type scope of JavaScript.

Well, you can create closures, e.g. using property descriptors argument:

```
var o = Object.create({inherited: 1}, {
  foo: {
    get: (function () { // a closure
      var closured = 'foo';
      return function () {
        return closured+'bar';
      };
    })()
  }
});

o.foo; // "foobar"
```

Note that I'm talking about the ECMAScript 5th Edition [`Object.create`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.5) method, not the Crockford's shim.

The method is starting to be natively implemented on latest browsers, check this [compatibility table](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/).

Comment: @CMS 2 questions.  1) Does the scope chain on Object.create(null) still terminate at the global scope (such as 'window' in a browser), or does it terminate on itself? 2) It is still not clear to me why Object.create was introduced (e.g. what feature was missing that this addressed?) and why one would use it instead of new Function();

Comment: @Matt, 1) the scope chain is not really a related concept here, scope chain is  related to **identifier resolution**, e.g.: how `foo;` is resolved in the current *lexical environment*. 2) To provide an easy way to implement inheritance, it's a really powerful construct. IMO I would use it because it's really simple and lightweight, but for production code, we still need to wait some time until ES5 is supported widely. About missing features, the fact of creating a "pristine" object, `Object.create(null);` was missing, it's really useful to implement reliable hash-table-like objects...

Comment: @CMS Thanks. So simply when you create a object by using 'Object.create',you get the ability to select the object that should be its prototype.

Comment: @CMS O.K., so `Object.create(null)` means you don't have to use `hasOwnProperty()` crap when iterating cause it inherits none???  I like that - thanks.  Of course, everybody is _still_ going to do `hasOwnProperty` since not everybody will use `Object.create(null)` so I'm not sure it's a real benefit...  So far I have found the other "benefits" of `Object.create()` completely unconvincing.

Answer (score 506):

Very simply said, `new X` is `Object.create(X.prototype)` with additionally running the `constructor` function. (And giving the `constructor` the chance to `return` the actual object that should be the result of the expression instead of `this`.)

That’s it. :)

The rest of the answers are just confusing, because apparently nobody else reads the definition of [new](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) either. ;)

Comment: +1  Simplicity and clarity!  (Though the Object.create(null) seems a nice option - maybe should mention that).

Comment: keep it simple that's the way to go

Comment: That just leaves the question of "wait, so _functions_ have prototypes _too_? What's the relationship between those and _object_ prototypes?"

Comment: @Qwertie: In JS, *everything* is an object. :) They copied that from Java, who copied it from SmallTalk, who went all the way to the end with it. It’s a nice case of “emergence”, making life easier in general.

Comment: @Evi1M4chine actually in Java, functions are not objects (and neither are primitives, for that matter)... and objects don't have prototypes, so the comparison seems un-fitting. The fact that JS works differently than other popular OO languages is a major source of confusion (and it doesn't help that browsers don't provide an easy way to visualize the network of objects including functions and prototypes). P.S. I found this link helpful : https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-objects-deconstruction

Comment: @Qwertie: I didn’t say that Java fully *did* follow that philosophy. They had the _philosophy_. They just half-assed it. :) But SmallTalk certainly followed it. … And OOP does not equal class-based OOP.. JS is prototype-based OOP, but they all have OOP in common. In fact JS’s OOP philosophy is much cleaner, more elegant and more universal than the class-based approach. They just failed to implement it nicely too. (JavaScript 2 was supposed to solve all that, and would have been quite nice. WebAssembly made all of it moot. :)

Comment: @Dmitry: Because some objects want to initialize external resources in their constructors (and destroy them in their destructors). Like file handles, sockets, network connections, memory areas, temporary files, GPU state, etc. E.g. a File object in a hypothetical language would be created by opening a file and getting the handle during its construction. A good garbage collector automatically calls the destructor and is smart about it by using the concept of volatile resources too, to not exhaust them.

Comment: @Dmitry: And returning an *other* object is very useful for the design pattern of singletons, for example. There, there is only ever one instance, and on creation, it does not return the new object, but the already existing one, and discards that newly created instance right away.

Comment: @Evi1M4chine I have deleted my comment as I cannot remember the mental state I was in writing it*(2018)

Answer (score 221):

Here are the steps that happen internally for both calls:
(Hint: the only difference is in step 3)

---

`new Test()`:

1. create `new Object()` obj
2. set `obj.__proto__` to `Test.prototype`
3. `return Test.call(obj) || obj;
   // normally obj is returned but constructors in JS can return a value`

---

`Object.create( Test.prototype )`

1. create `new Object()` obj
2. set `obj.__proto__` to `Test.prototype`
3. `return obj;`

---

So basically `Object.create` doesn't execute the constructor.

Comment: @Ray so using object.create we font have the properties of function mentioned in constructor function?

Comment: @sortednoun as long as the properties are private and not specified on the prototype, **yes, they won't be inherited and you won't have them in the new object** (and, I would add, you can expect to get eventual prototyped properties from the parent, just when the parent constructor has been execute at least once).

Comment: As with most constructor functions the methods are defined within the returned object, `new` basically has all functions duplicated, while `Object.create` doesn't.

Comment: This was the important difference to me. If my prototype has props with values and I use `Object.create()` and then try to say get the value of those props on the object, I'll get `undefined` whereas since `new()` runs the constructor, I can immediately query prop values.

Answer (score 64):

Let me try to explain (more on [Blog](https://nodeway.wordpress.com/2015/02/16/javascript-prototype/)) :

1. When you write `Car` constructor `var Car = function(){}`, this is how things are internally:
   [image: A diagram of prototypal chains when creating javascript objects]
   We have one `{prototype}` hidden link to `Function.prototype` which is not accessible and one `prototype` link to `Car.prototype` which is accessible and has an actual `constructor` of `Car`. Both Function.prototype and Car.prototype have hidden links to `Object.prototype`.
2. When we want to create two equivalent objects by using the `new` operator and `create` method then we have to do it like this: `Honda = new Car();` and `Maruti = Object.create(Car.prototype)`.[image: A diagram of prototypal chains for differing object creation methods]
   What is happening?

   **`Honda = new Car();`** — When you create an object like this then hidden `{prototype}` property is pointed to `Car.prototype`. So here, the `{prototype}` of the Honda object will always be `Car.prototype` — we don't have any option to change the `{prototype}` property of the object. What if I want to change the prototype of our newly created object?
   **`Maruti = Object.create(Car.prototype)`** — When you create an object like this you have an extra option to choose your object's `{prototype}` property. If you want Car.prototype as the `{prototype}` then pass it as a parameter in the function. If you don't want any `{prototype}` for your object then you can pass `null` like this: `Maruti = Object.create(null)`.

*Conclusion — By using the method `Object.create` you have the freedom to choose your object `{prototype}` property. In `new Car();`, you don't have that freedom.*

**Preferred way in OO JavaScript :**

Suppose we have two objects `a` and `b`.

```
var a = new Object();
var b = new Object();
```

Now, suppose `a` has some methods which `b` also wants to access. For that, we require object inheritance (`a` should be the prototype of `b` only if we want access to those methods). If we check the prototypes of `a` and `b` then we will find out that they share the prototype `Object.prototype`.

```
Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf(b); //true
a.isPrototypeOf(b); //false (the problem comes into the picture here).
```

*Problem —* we want object `a` as the prototype of `b`, but here we created object `b` with the prototype `Object.prototype`.
*Solution —* ECMAScript 5 introduced `Object.create()`, to achieve such inheritance easily. If we create object `b` like this:

```
var b = Object.create(a);
```

then,

```
a.isPrototypeOf(b);// true (problem solved, you included object a in the prototype chain of object b.)
```

So, if you are doing object oriented scripting then `Object.create()` is very useful for inheritance.

Comment: So, it is somewhat similar to object creation without constructor invocation?
We will enjoy all the benefits of the class. The obj instanceof Class will also be true. But we are not invoking the Class function via new.

Comment: @Anshul You said that `a.isPrototypeOf(b);` will return `false` which is right, because both Objects are different and pointing to different memory. The correct way to do this with the `new` operator is here. - https://jsfiddle.net/167onunp/ .

Comment: Why wouldn't you just set the prototype property of b to a, instead of doing this?

Comment: Liked the article on your blog too. Helped me understand the concept much better. Thank you.

Comment: The conclusion says it all.

Comment: Note that on all modern JavaScript implementations the 'hidden' `[[Prototype]]` can be accessed as `__proto__` (non-standard) and with the `Object.getPrototypeOf` function.

Answer (score 50):

This:

```
var foo = new Foo();
```

and

```
var foo = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
```

are quite similar.  One important difference is that `new Foo` actually runs constructor code, whereas `Object.create` will not execute code such as

```
function Foo() {
    alert("This constructor does not run with Object.create");
}
```

Note that if you use the two-parameter version of `Object.create()` then you can do much more powerful things.

Comment: Great explanation. Might I add,  using `Object.create` in its simplest form like this allows you to omit constructor functions from your code while taking advantage of prototype inheritance.

Answer (score 23):

The difference is the so-called "pseudoclassical vs. prototypal inheritance". The suggestion is to use only one type in your code, not mixing the two.

In pseudoclassical inheritance (with "new" operator), imagine that you first define a pseudo-class, and then create objects from that class. For example, define a pseudo-class "Person", and then create "Alice" and "Bob" from "Person".

In prototypal inheritance (using Object.create), you directly create a specific person "Alice", and then create another person "Bob" using "Alice" as a prototype. There is no "class" here; all are objects.

Internally, JavaScript uses "prototypal inheritance"; the "pseudoclassical" way is just some sugar.

See [this link](http://www.theoryapp.com/javascript-inheritance-pseudoclassical-vs-prototypal/) for a comparison of the two ways.

Answer (score 23):

**Object creation variants.**

---

**Variant 1** : '**new Object()**' -> Object constructor without arguments.

```
var p1 = new Object(); // 'new Object()' create and return empty object -> {}

var p2 = new Object(); // 'new Object()' create and return empty object -> {}

console.log(p1); // empty object -> {}

console.log(p2); // empty object -> {}

// p1 and p2 are pointers to different objects
console.log(p1 === p2); // false

console.log(p1.prototype); // undefined

// empty object which is in fact Object.prototype
console.log(p1.__proto__); // {}

// empty object to which p1.__proto__ points
console.log(Object.prototype); // {}

console.log(p1.__proto__ === Object.prototype); // true

// null, which is in fact Object.prototype.__proto__
console.log(p1.__proto__.__proto__); // null

console.log(Object.prototype.__proto__); // null
```

[image]

---

**Variant 2** : '**new Object(person)**' -> Object constructor with argument.

```
const person = {
    name: 'no name',
    lastName: 'no lastName',
    age: -1
}

// 'new Object(person)' return 'person', which is pointer to the object ->
//  -> { name: 'no name', lastName: 'no lastName', age: -1 }
var p1 = new Object(person);

// 'new Object(person)' return 'person', which is pointer to the object ->
//  -> { name: 'no name', lastName: 'no lastName', age: -1 }
var p2 = new Object(person);

// person, p1 and p2 are pointers to the same object
console.log(p1 === p2); // true
console.log(p1 === person); // true
console.log(p2 === person); // true

p1.name = 'John'; // change 'name' by 'p1'
p2.lastName = 'Doe'; // change 'lastName' by 'p2'
person.age = 25; // change 'age' by 'person'

// when print 'p1', 'p2' and 'person', it's the same result,
// because the object they points is the same
console.log(p1); // { name: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', age: 25 }
console.log(p2); // { name: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', age: 25 }
console.log(person); // { name: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', age: 25 }
```

[image]

---

**Variant 3.1** : '**Object.create(person)**'. Use Object.create with simple object 'person'. 'Object.create(person)' will create(and return) new empty object and add property '__proto__' to the same new empty object. This property '__proto__' will point to the object 'person'.

```
const person = {
        name: 'no name',
        lastName: 'no lastName',
        age: -1,
        getInfo: function getName() {
           return `${this.name} ${this.lastName}, ${this.age}!`;
    }
}

var p1 = Object.create(person);

var p2 = Object.create(person);

// 'p1.__proto__' and 'p2.__proto__' points to
// the same object -> 'person'
// { name: 'no name', lastName: 'no lastName', age: -1, getInfo: [Function: getName] }
console.log(p1.__proto__);
console.log(p2.__proto__);
console.log(p1.__proto__ === p2.__proto__); // true

console.log(person.__proto__); // {}(which is the Object.prototype)

// 'person', 'p1' and 'p2' are different
console.log(p1 === person); // false
console.log(p1 === p2); // false
console.log(p2 === person); // false

// { name: 'no name', lastName: 'no lastName', age: -1, getInfo: [Function: getName] }
console.log(person);

console.log(p1); // empty object - {}

console.log(p2); // empty object - {}

// add properties to object 'p1'
// (properties with the same names like in object 'person')
p1.name = 'John';
p1.lastName = 'Doe';
p1.age = 25;

// add properties to object 'p2'
// (properties with the same names like in object 'person')
p2.name = 'Tom';
p2.lastName = 'Harrison';
p2.age = 38;

// { name: 'no name', lastName: 'no lastName', age: -1, getInfo: [Function: getName] }
console.log(person);

// { name: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', age: 25 }
console.log(p1);

// { name: 'Tom', lastName: 'Harrison', age: 38 }
console.log(p2);

// use by '__proto__'(link from 'p1' to 'person'),
// person's function 'getInfo'
console.log(p1.getInfo()); // John Doe, 25!

// use by '__proto__'(link from 'p2' to 'person'),
// person's function 'getInfo'
console.log(p2.getInfo()); // Tom Harrison, 38!
```

[image]

---

**Variant 3.2** : '**Object.create(Object.prototype)**'. Use Object.create with built-in object -> 'Object.prototype'. 'Object.create(Object.prototype)' will create(and return) new empty object and add property '__proto__' to the same new empty object. This property '__proto__' will point to the object 'Object.prototype'.

```
// 'Object.create(Object.prototype)' :
// 1. create and return empty object -> {}.
// 2. add to 'p1' property '__proto__', which is link to 'Object.prototype'
var p1 = Object.create(Object.prototype);

// 'Object.create(Object.prototype)' :
// 1. create and return empty object -> {}.
// 2. add to 'p2' property '__proto__', which is link to 'Object.prototype'
var p2 = Object.create(Object.prototype);

console.log(p1); // {}

console.log(p2); // {}

console.log(p1 === p2); // false

console.log(p1.prototype); // undefined

console.log(p2.prototype); // undefined

console.log(p1.__proto__ === Object.prototype); // true

console.log(p2.__proto__ === Object.prototype); // true
```

[image]

---

**Variant 4** : '**new SomeFunction()**'

```
// 'this' in constructor-function 'Person'
// represents a new instace,
// that will be created by 'new Person(...)'
// and returned implicitly
function Person(name, lastName, age) {

    this.name = name;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // !--- only for demonstration ---
    // if add function 'getInfo' into
    // constructor-function 'Person',
    // then all instances will have a copy of the function 'getInfo'!
    //
    // this.getInfo: function getInfo() {
    //  return this.name + " " + this.lastName + ", " + this.age + "!";
    // }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
}

// 'Person.prototype' is an empty object
// (before add function 'getInfo')
console.log(Person.prototype); // Person {}

// With 'getInfo' added to 'Person.prototype',
// instances by their properties '__proto__',
// will have access to the function 'getInfo'.
// With this approach, instances not need
// a copy of the function 'getInfo' for every instance.
Person.prototype.getInfo = function getInfo() {
    return this.name + " " + this.lastName + ", " + this.age + "!";
}

// after function 'getInfo' is added to 'Person.prototype'
console.log(Person.prototype); // Person { getInfo: [Function: getInfo] }

// create instance 'p1'
var p1 = new Person('John', 'Doe', 25);

// create instance 'p2'
var p2 = new Person('Tom', 'Harrison', 38);

// Person { name: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', age: 25 }
console.log(p1);

// Person { name: 'Tom', lastName: 'Harrison', age: 38 }
console.log(p2);

// 'p1.__proto__' points to 'Person.prototype'
console.log(p1.__proto__); // Person { getInfo: [Function: getInfo] }

// 'p2.__proto__' points to 'Person.prototype'
console.log(p2.__proto__); // Person { getInfo: [Function: getInfo] }

console.log(p1.__proto__ === p2.__proto__); // true

// 'p1' and 'p2' points to different objects(instaces of 'Person')
console.log(p1 === p2); // false

// 'p1' by its property '__proto__' reaches 'Person.prototype.getInfo' 
// and use 'getInfo' with 'p1'-instance's data
console.log(p1.getInfo()); // John Doe, 25!

// 'p2' by its property '__proto__' reaches 'Person.prototype.getInfo' 
// and use 'getInfo' with 'p2'-instance's data
console.log(p2.getInfo()); // Tom Harrison, 38!
```

[image]

Comment: Nice Summary. Thanks. It helped me today !!

Comment: `===` operator is intricate here since I don't understand how it works on your second explanation. `==` would be hunky-dory but `===`.

Answer (score 22):

```
function Test(){
    this.prop1 = 'prop1';
    this.prop2 = 'prop2';
    this.func1 = function(){
        return this.prop1 + this.prop2;
    }
};

Test.prototype.protoProp1 = 'protoProp1';
Test.prototype.protoProp2 = 'protoProp2';
var newKeywordTest = new Test();
var objectCreateTest = Object.create(Test.prototype);

/* Object.create   */
console.log(objectCreateTest.prop1); // undefined
console.log(objectCreateTest.protoProp1); // protoProp1 
console.log(objectCreateTest.__proto__.protoProp1); // protoProp1

/* new    */
console.log(newKeywordTest.prop1); // prop1
console.log(newKeywordTest.__proto__.protoProp1); // protoProp1
```

Summary:

1) with `new` keyword there are two things to note;

a) function is used as a constructor

b) `function.prototype` object is passed to the `__proto__` property ... or where `__proto__` is not supported, it is the second place where the new object looks to find properties

2) with `Object.create(obj.prototype)` you are constructing an object (`obj.prototype`) and passing it to the intended object ..with the difference that now new object's `__proto__` is also pointing to obj.prototype (please ref ans by xj9 for that)

Answer (score 13):

Accordingly to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3658673/3612353) and to [this video](https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=advanced-javascript&author=kyle-simpson&name=advanced-javascript-m2&clip=19&mode=live) `new` keyword does next things:

1. Creates new object.
2. Links new object to constructor function (`prototype`).
3. Makes `this` variable point to the new object.
4. Executes constructor function using the new object and implicit perform `return this`;
5. Assigns constructor function name to new object's property `constructor`.

`Object.create` performs only `1st` and `2nd` steps!!!

Answer (score 12):

Internally `Object.create` does this:

```
Object.create = function (o) {
    function F() {}
    F.prototype = o;
    return new F();
};
```

The syntax just takes away the illusion that JavaScript uses Classical Inheritance.

Comment: The ECMAScript 5 [`Object.create`](http://sideshowbarker.github.com/es5-spec/#x15.2.3.5) method, does a lot more than that, you can define properties by *property descriptors* and you can create an object that doesn't inherit from anything (`Object.create(null);`), this type of shims should be avoided because you can't really emulate that behavior on ES3. [More info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830800/object-defineproperty-in-es5/3844768#3844768)

Comment: Agree with @CMS but in general, it is simple polyfill for `Object.create`.

Answer (score 1):

`Object.create(Constructor.prototype)` is the part of `new Constructor`

### this is `new Constructor` implementation

```js
// 1. define constructor function

      function myConstructor(name, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
      }
      myConstructor.prototype.greet = function(){
        console.log(this.name, this.age)
      };

// 2. new operator implementation

      let newOperatorWithConstructor = function(name, age) {
        const newInstance = new Object(); // empty object
        Object.setPrototypeOf(newInstance, myConstructor.prototype); // set prototype

        const bindedConstructor = myConstructor.bind(newInstance); // this binding
        bindedConstructor(name, age); // execute binded constructor function

        return newInstance; // return instance
      };

// 3. produce new instance

      const instance = new myConstructor("jun", 28);
      const instance2 = newOperatorWithConstructor("jun", 28);
      console.log(instance);
      console.log(instance2);
```

### `new Constructor` implementation contains `Object.create` method

```js
      newOperatorWithConstructor = function(name, age) {
        const newInstance = Object.create(myConstructor.prototype); // empty object, prototype chaining

        const bindedConstructor = myConstructor.bind(newInstance); // this binding
        bindedConstructor(name, age); // execute binded constructor function

        return newInstance; // return instance
      };

      console.log(newOperatorWithConstructor("jun", 28));
```

Comment: Don't use `new Object`, use an object literal.

Comment: Don't use `.bind(x)(...args)`, just `.call(x, ...args)`.

Comment: @Bergi `.apply(x, args)` ;-)