# JavaScript inheritance: Object.create vs new

Tags: javascript, inheritance, object-create

In JavaScript what is the difference between these two examples:

Prerequisite:

```
function SomeBaseClass(){
}

SomeBaseClass.prototype = {
    doThis : function(){
    },

    doThat : function(){
    }
}
```

Inheritance example A using Object.create:

```
function MyClass(){
}

MyClass.prototype = Object.create(SomeBaseClass.prototype);
```

Inheritance example B using the new keyword

```
function MyClass(){
}

MyClass.prototype = new SomeBaseClass();
```

Both examples seem to do the same thing. When would you chose one over the other?

An additional question:
Consider code in below link (line 15), where a reference to the the function's own constructor is stored in the prototype. Why is this useful?

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/loaders/ImageLoader.js

Excerpt (if you don't want to open the link):

```
THREE.ImageLoader.prototype = {

    constructor: THREE.ImageLoader
}
```

Comment: Why the heck is this marked as duplicate!?!  The other question, and answers, don't even mention `Object.create`.  This is a mistake, and should be reopened.

Comment: If anything, it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166616/understanding-the-difference-between-object-create-and-new-somefunction-in-j

Comment: 13 votes on that comment and still not reopened..?!

Answer (score 115, accepted):

In your question you have mentioned that `Both examples seem to do the same thing`, It's not true at all, because

### Your first example

```
function SomeBaseClass(){...}
SomeBaseClass.prototype = {
    doThis : function(){...},
    doThat : function(){...}
}
function MyClass(){...}
MyClass.prototype = Object.create(SomeBaseClass.prototype);
```

In this example, you are just inheriting `SomeBaseClass' prototype` but what if you have a property in your `SomeBaseClass` like

```
function SomeBaseClass(){ 
    this.publicProperty='SomeValue'; 
}
```

and if you use it like

```
var obj=new MyClass();
console.log(obj.publicProperty); // undefined
​console.log(obj);​
```

The `obj` object won't have `publicProperty` property like [in this example](http://jsfiddle.net/dhWmz/1/).

### Your second example

```
MyClass.prototype = new SomeBaseClass();
```

It's executing the `constructor` function, making an instance of `SomeBaseClass` and inheriting the whole `SomeBaseClass` object. So, if you use

```
    var obj=new MyClass();
    console.log(obj.publicProperty); // SomeValue
    console.log(obj);​
```

In this case its `publicProperty` property is also available to the `obj` object like [in this example](http://jsfiddle.net/smBkH/).

Since the `Object.create` is not available in some old browsers, in that case you can use

```
if(!Object.create)
{
    Object.create=function(o){
        function F(){}
        F.prototype=o;
        return new F();
    }
}
```

Above code just adds `Object.create` function if it's not available so you can use `Object.create` function and I think the code above describes what `Object.create` actually does. Hope it'll help in some way.

Comment: Hi Sheikh. Thanks for your efforts on this. Yes, the differences is that the constructor is ran in the second example but not in the first. (which is desirable in my case). Regarding the undefined public property that is not inherited from the super implementation, you just need to call super in the child's constructor:  SomeBaseClass.call(this). Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NhQGB/

Comment: I've been looking for a super simple way of proper inheritance in JS without using any libraries / frameworks. I think this example (in my fiddle above) is the best approach for modern browsers. Perhaps the Object.Create polyfill could add support for legacy browsers?

Comment: so basically to summarize, if you do .prototype = new then you are inheriting any values you assigned to this in the base class, and when you do object.create you are ONLY inheriting what is on the prototype in the base class, right?

Comment: Doest this "MyClass.prototype = new SomeBaseClass()" mean that new instance of SomeBaseClass is created when instance of MyClass is not created yet?

Comment: No, only when you create the main object the prototype is set to that `SomeBaseClass`.

Comment: there are a profusion of topics concerning that yet no explanation like yours. +1

Answer (score 40):

> Both examples seem to do the same thing.

That's true in your case.

> When would you chose one over the other?

When `SomeBaseClass` has a function body, this would get executed with the `new` keyword. This usually is not intended - you only want to set up the prototype chain. In some cases it even could cause serious issues because you actually *instantiate* an object, whose private-scoped variables are shared by all `MyClass` instances as they inherit the same privileged methods. Other side effects are imaginable.

So, you should generally prefer `Object.create`. Yet, it is not supported in some legacy browsers; which is the reason you see the `new`-approach much too frequent as it often does no (obvious) harm. Also have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12593269/1048572).

Comment: This is the best answer, well explained

Answer (score 8):

The difference becomes obvious if you use `Object.create()` as it is intended. Actually, it does entirely hideout the `prototype` word from your code, it'll do the job under the hood. Using `Object.create()`, we can go like

```
var base =  {
    doThis : function(){
    },

    doThat : function(){
    }
};
```

And then we can extend/inherit other objects from this

```
var myObject = Object.create( base );
// myObject will now link to "base" via the prototype chain internally
```

So this is another concept, a more "object oriented" way of inherting. There is no "constructor function" out of the box using `Object.create()` for instance. But of course you could just create and call a self defined *constructor function* within those objects.

One argument for using `Object.create()` is that it might look more *natural* to *mix*/*inherit* from other objects, than using Javascripts *default way*.

Comment: `Object.create` can't really replace the classical approach with `new` when a constructor function is needed

Comment: It most definitely can @Bergi. Look at this blog post: http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-objects-deconstruction. You can also pass an initialization object as a second parameter to Object.create().

Comment: @LocalPCGuy: No it cannot, because `Object.create` does not call a function that would be necessary to create closures. Of course, with `Object.create` you can put an `init` method on your objects and call that immediately and it maybe even returns `this` so that you get concise syntax - but wait, that *is* a constructor then.

Comment: Calling an init function works similarly to a constructor, but it is not a constructor. And that method does allow you exactly replace the classical approach with Object.create. And the mental model of the object linkage is much simpler than the one created via 'new'.

Comment: Well, my mental model of `new` uses "object linkage", so there's not much difference. In fact, there are only two things: `.constructor` is called `.init`, and that function doesn't have a `.prototype` property pointing back to your prototype object. The rest is just syntax - and I prefer `new X` over `Object.create(x).init()`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in java script but here is a simple example to understand difference between "Object.create" and "new" ..

step 1 : create the parent function with some properties and actions..

```
function Person() {

this.name = 'venkat';

this.address = 'dallas';

this.mobile='xxxxxxxxxx'

}

Person.prototype.func1 = function () {

    return this.name + this.address;
}
```

step 2 : create a child function (PersonSalary) which extends above Person function using **New** keyword..

```
function PersonSalary() {
    Person.call(this);
}
PersonSalary.prototype = new Person();

PersonSalary();
```

step 3 : create second child function (PersonLeaves) which extends above Person function using **Object.create** keyword..

```
function PersonLeaves() {
 Person.call(this);
}
PersonLeaves.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);


PersonLeaves();
```

// Now check both child functions prototypes.

```
PersonSalary.prototype
PersonLeaves.prototype
```

both of these child functions will link to Person(parent function) prototype and can access it's methods but if you create child function using new it will return a brand new object with all parent properties which we don't need and also when you create any object or function using "New" that parent function is executed which we don't want to be.

Here are the takeaways

> if you just want to  delegate to some methods in parent function and don't want a new object to be created , using Object.create is best way.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of additions to this answer set, mindful that JS obviously now has native classes:

1. In both Example A and Example B the static inheritance chain is not configured.
2. In Example B the superclass constructor is run at the "wrong time". It is run before the call to instantiate an instance of the subclass, before any arguments are known and perhaps before you have decided to instantiate an instance of the subclass. Note that constructors can contain any logic they like, including side-effectful logic, so this can be impactful.

Post-ES6 the inheritance chain can be configured in a standardised way using the `class` and `extends` keywords (which solve both of these issues).

See [also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67651986/38522).