# Why are my JavaScript object properties being overwritten by other instances?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

I created an object like the following.

```
var BaseObject = function(){

var base = this;
base.prop;

base.setProp = function(val){
    base.prop = val;
}
}
```

When I call the `setProp` method, I get the following.

```
var a = new BaseObject();
var b = new BaseObject();           

a.setProp("foo");
b.setProp("bar");

console.log(a.prop); // outputs 'foo'
console.log(b.prop); // outputs 'bar'
```

I then created another object that inherits from `BaseObject` like this.

```
var TestObject = function(){
    // do something
}

TestObject.prototype = new BaseObject();
```

When I do the same, I get a result I wasn't expecting.

```
var a = new TestObject();
var b = new TestObject();

a.setProp("foo");
b.setProp("bar");

console.log(a.prop); // outputs 'bar'
console.log(b.prop); // outputs 'bar'
```

I don't know why. I've been reading alot about closures and prototypal inheritance recently and I suspect I've gotten it all confused. So any pointers on why this particular example works the way it does would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's only one prototype instance, so all the instances of "TestObject" share it.  That is, there's only one "base".

Comment: So I need to set the prototype every time I create an instance?

Comment: @gargantaun: If you want `prop` to work properly, put it in the `BaseObject.prototype`. i.e.: `BaseObject.prototype.prop`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one `BaseObject` instance from which all `TestObject`s inherit. Don't use instances for creating prototype chains!

What you want is:

```
var TestObject = function(){
    BaseObject.call(this); // give this instance own properties from BaseObject
    // do something
}
TestObject.prototype = Object.create(BaseObject.prototype);
```

See [JavaScript inheritance: Object.create vs new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040684/javascript-inheritance-object-create-vs-new/13040858#13040858), [Correct javascript inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898786/correct-javascript-inheritance/10898859#10898859) and [What is the reason to use the 'new' keyword at Derived.prototype = new Base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592913/what-is-the-reason-to-use-the-new-keyword-here/12593049#12593049) for a detailed explanation of the problems with `new`. Also have a look at [Crockford's Prototypal inheritance - Issues with nested objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10131052/1048572)

Answer (score 2):

Think of protoypal inheritance as dealing solely with objects and without the concept of classes.  In your code you have a `BaseObject` object which has a `prop` attribute.  You have 2 other objects that extend from 1 instance of that object, but the property belongs to the original object.  If you need each object to have their own copy, then they need to be given a distinct variable that is intialized for that object (such as in their constructor).

As an aside the Java style accessors are overkill in JavaScript (you can intercept access natively if needed) and can further muddy these questions since they will behave differently.

Comment: So TestObject needs to have it's own `prop` property. And Anything that inherits from TestObject also needs it's own `prop` property? And so on?

Comment: Yes, just like with classical inheritance but you have to implement it differently by ensuring that the constructors are called the proper way or mixins are used so that all instance data is where it belongs.