# Call the parent's method?

Tags: javascript

Call the parent method.How to implement?

```
 function Ch() {
        this.year = function (n) {
            return n
        }
    }

    function Pant() {
        this.name = 'Kelli';
        this.year = function (n) {
            return 5 + n
        }
    }
```

//extends

```
 Pant.prototype = new Ch();
    Pant.prototype.constructor = Pant;
    pant = new Pant();
    alert(pant.name); //Kelli
    alert(pant.year(5)) //10
```

How to сall the parent method

```
this.year = function (n) {
            return 5 + n
        }
```

in object?Thank you all for your help

Comment: `Pant`? `Parent`? Are these the same? If so, does `Ch` stand for `Child`? If it does, then your naming is very confusing since the Parent in inheriting from the Child.

Comment: ...anyway, you're calling `.year()` successfully, so I'm not sure what your question actually is.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13167717/1048572)

Comment: Why is your `year` method not on the prototype of `Ch`? If there is a reason, please show us your actual code; else move it.

Comment: All methods must be in prototype?Why?

Comment: @zloctb: They need not, but should. Else every instantiation would create a new function - see [prototype vs this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/310870/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13167717/1048572) to your code:

```
function Ch() {
    this.year = function(n) {
        return n;
    }
}

function Pant() {
    Ch.call(this); // make this Pant also a Ch instance
    this.name = 'Kelli';
    var oldyear = this.year;
    this.year = function (n) {
        return 5 + oldyear(n);
    };
}
// Let Pant inherit from Ch
Pant.prototype = Object.create(Ch.prototype, {constructor:{value:Pant}});

var pant = new Pant();
alert(pant.name); // Kelli
alert(pant.year(5)) // 10
```

Comment: The questions is confusing, but I believe OP just wants to call `Pant.prototype.year` (considering the `prototype` from the original code, not the one returned by `Object.create`).

Comment: @bfavaretto: Yes, it is confusing. Yet the method is not on the prototype, unfortunately...

Answer (score 1):

You can call overridden supper class(Parent) methods using `__proto__` but it is not supported by IE

```
alert(pant.__proto__.year(5)) //5
```

Comment: This property is not supported in ie.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how [Google's Closure Library](https://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/namespace_goog.html) implements inheritance:

```
goog.inherits = function(childCtor, parentCtor) {
  function tempCtor() {};
  tempCtor.prototype = parentCtor.prototype;
  childCtor.superClass_ = parentCtor.prototype;
  childCtor.prototype = new tempCtor();
  childCtor.prototype.constructor = childCtor;
};
```

Your code would then become something like:

```
function Ch() {}
Ch.prototype.year = 
function (n) {
   return n
}

function Pant() {}
goog.inherits(Pant,Ch);
Pant.prototype.name = 'Kelli';
Pant.prototype.year = function (n) {
   return 5 + Pant.superClass_.year.call(this, n);//Call the parent class
}

pant = new Pant();
alert(pant.name); //Kelli
alert(pant.year(5)) //10
```

You could of course rename the `goog.inherits` function if you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, assuming `Ch` is for "child", and `Pant` for "parent", you are doing it backwards, which is extremely confusing. When you say

```
Pant.prototype = new Ch();
```

You're making `Pant` inherit from `Ch`. I'm assuming that's really what you mean, and that you want to call the method that returns `n`, instead of the one that returns `n + 5`. So you can do this:

```
function Ch() {
    this.year = function (n) {
        return n;
    }
}

function Pant() {
    this.name = 'Kelli';
    this.year = function (n) {
        return 5 + n;
    }
}

Pant.prototype = new Ch();
Pant.prototype.constructor = Pant;
pant = new Pant();
alert(pant.name); //Kelli
alert(pant.year(5)) //10

// Is the below what you need?
alert(Pant.prototype.year(5)); // 5
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JNn5K/