# Calling Superclass Method From Subclass - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, canvas, subclass, superclass

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [set attribute with javascript super method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13167386/set-attribute-with-javascript-super-method)

I am trying to create a simple game in HTML5 for fun. I have an Entity class that is supposed to be the superclass of the Player class.

```
function Entity(x, y) {

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    this.tick = function() {
        //Do generic stuff
    }
}

function Player(x, y) {

    this.parent.constructor.call(this, x, y);

    this.tick = function() {
        //Do player-specific stuff
        this.parent.tick.call(this);
    }
}

Player.prototype = new Entity();
Player.prototype.constructor = Player;
Player.prototype.parent = Entity.prototype;
```

The problem is at this line:

```
this.parent.tick.call(this);
```

I get an error displayed in the JavaScript console of chrome: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined".

I don't get it and I've spent a long time trying to find posts of a similar issue. My call to the superclass' constructor works fine but the call to the superclass' tick method does not work.

I'm very new to making games so I have no idea if this a good setup (calling superclass tick from subclass tick). If there is a better, more typical way that people use, please tell.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you have the generic stuff on the prototype? You could easily access it there.

Comment: javascript has no classical inheritance like you are used from other classical languages like java. You should read into prototypal inheritance and learn about it's differences to the classical one.

Answer (score 7):

Adapting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13167717/1048572) to your code:

```
function Entity(x, y) {

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    this.tick = function() {
        //Do generic stuff
    }
}

function Player(x, y) {

    this.parent.constructor.call(this, x, y);

    var oldtick = this.tick;
    this.tick = function() {
        //Do player-specific stuff
        oldtick.call(this);
    }
}

Player.prototype = Object.create(Entity.prototype);
Player.prototype.constructor = Player;
Player.prototype.parent = Entity.prototype;
```

Comment: I have a doubt. Why do we need to pass `this` in: `this.parent.constructor.call(this, x, y);`. Well I know, this would work like this. but I din't find any explanation for this.

Comment: @VeerShrivastav: You need to pass the instance because otherwise the constructor wouldn't know where to set up its properties.

Answer (score 4):

Your question inspired me to look around and I found what I think is [a great article by Josh Gertzen](http://joshgertzen.com/object-oriented-super-class-method-calling-with-javascript/) about this concept.

I blatantly copy from his article some code to set up an `extends` method on classes:

```
function Class() { }
Class.prototype.construct = function() {};
Class.extend = function(def)
{
    var classDef = function()
    {
        if (arguments[0] !== Class)
        {
            this.construct.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    };
    var proto = new this(Class);
    var superClass = this.prototype;
    for (var n in def)
    {
        var item = def[n];                      
        if (item instanceof Function) item.$ = superClass;
        proto[n] = item;
    }
    classDef.prototype = proto;
    classDef.extend = this.extend;      
    return classDef;
};
```

After which your case is as simple as:

```
var Entity = Class.extend({
    tick: function()
    {
        alert('Entity tick');
    }
});

var Player = Entity.extend({
    tick: function()
    {
        alert('Player tick');
        arguments.callee.$.tick.call(this);
    }
});

p = new Player();
p.tick();
```

Which will alert `Player tick` and then `Entity tick`.

Comment: Looks like a overcomplication to me :-)

Comment: +1 for effort, although Bergi answer is cleaner.

Comment: If this is the only superclass call in the application, it's an overcomplication of course. But I find that the second block of code is clearer than the other methods. And you only need to copy-paste the first block once and then forget about it; no more thinking about prototypes :-)

Comment: Yeah... It's an overcomplicated answer, but the link did remind me of the 'call' and 'apply' methods, which allow you to set the 'context' (this == 'context') of a function call, and that was useful enough for me.