# Inheritance and "TypeError: Cannot read property 'someProperty' of undefined"

Tags: javascript

PROBLEM: When inheriting an object's properties and methods, a child object seems to loose connection with parent's 'this'. To illustrate it better, look at my example:

```
function RigidBody() {
    this.local = new Matrix4x3();
    this.position = new vec3();
    ...
}

RigidBody.prototype = {
    ...
    setPosition: function(vec) {
        this.position.copy(vec);
        this.local.setTranslation(this.position);
    }
    ...
};

CameraObject.prototype = new RigidBody();
CameraObject.prototype.constructor = CameraObject;

function CameraObject() {
    this.fov = ...
}

CameraObject.prototype.add = ...;

var camera = new CameraObject();
camera.add(...); // Works fine;
camera.setTranslation(...); // Throws "TypeError: Cannot read property 'setTranslation' of undefined
// And on another PC it throws: "http://localhost:8080/js/rigidBody.js(61): Uncaught exception: TypeError: Cannot convert 'this.local' to object"
```

How to bypass it? I found a workaround for this problem by assigning `this.this = this;` to parental object and replacing every this by this.this. Unfortunately as a result I need to add .this to every camera function call like this: `camera.this.setPosition(...);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as a general advice, please add `console.log(camera)` to your code and inspect the object in a good browser console, I highly recommend [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)

that way you can explore what properties and nested properties are available to `camera` object

---

from your code example in original question, `setTranslation` appears to be a property of `camera.local`, not `camera` itself.

or perhaps you wanted to call `camera.setPosition(...);` given that you added it to `RigidBody`'s prototype, but never used it afterwards - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deathApril/AJch3/)?

---

and given the code provided in comment below:

```
function Matrix4x3(){
    this.element = new Float32Array(16);
}
```

which does not define `setTranslation`, so `this.local.setTranslation` might be undefined as well..

Comment: Camera by itself does not contain `.local`, I'd like to treat it as an extension to `RigidBody` object, and because of this, it does not contain `setPosition` too. So by inheriting `RigidBody` object by any other object will allow me to manipulate this object in a 3D world.

Comment: not sure what's your definition of *"itelf"*, but `camera`'s prototype DOES contain both `local` and `setPosition` - that is the whole point of prototypes and inheritance, that the object has access to all the properties of its prototype and inherited prototype, ...

Comment: I meant that `CameraObject` by itself does not contains `.local` before inheriting it from `RigidBody`. Anyway you are absolutely right, and now I'm like "WTF, why in my case it is not working properly?!" BTW for me it looks like after inheriting `RigidBody`, its inherited prototypes still tries to use it's original parent properties (look at the last line of my main post here which I added recently, maybe it would be a new hint)

Comment: I believe `Matrix4x3` might not be a proper constructor or it might return some funny value instead of an object??

Comment: When I manually merge those two objects, it works flawlessly, so I believe that the problem does not lie in those kind of things. Anyway this is what `Matrix4x3` look like: [img](http://screenshooter.net/0277897/xemmaan)

Comment: i see, it looks as if you had no idea which methods are available to `camera`, which to `camera.local` and so on.. please use a proper IDE which will display available properties or a debugging tool like Firebug..

Comment: `setTranslation` is a prototype of `Matrix4x3`, but I didn't show it on a picture, because there are lots of prototypes in there. `Float32Array` is just a native JavaScript array object, which is use in my case in WebGL app. Also, thanks for the Firebug recommendation, I will surely use it to debug my problem. BTW just before a moment I created an another object and in it's case inheritance works without any problems. So I guess that the 'CameraObject' is not well constructed. BTW2 is it possible to object have a proto which by itself uses `this.local`, but will inherit later?

Comment: Ok, I found the problem - somewhere in `CameraObject` code I have created an array of `local`'s (in order to support multiple cameras, but instead of assigning old `local`'s to the array cell, I have assigned it to the whole array, like this: 
`this.inactiveLocals = [];
this.inactiveLocals = new Matrix4x3();` Firebug is awesome ;]

Answer (score -1):

You need to call "super", in other words, inherit the properties from the parent constructor:

```
function CameraObject() {
    RigidBody.call(this); // inherit RigidBody properties
    this.fov = ...
}
```

Comment: When I call 'super' that way, the problem don't disappear, but strangely, now it throws an error one line earlier: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'copy' of undefined"

Comment: you don't need to call any "super" when using prototypical inheritance - see comparison of calling super and prototypes in http://stackoverflow.com/a/13167725/1176601,, and e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/deathApril/AJch3/1/ applied to original question code