# Why is object property changed for all instances?

Tags: javascript

I wanted to encapsulate the position of a sprite within another object. So that instead of using `tile.x` and `tile.y` I would access via `tile.position.x` and `tile.position.y`.

Yet once I set the value of `tile.position` within the init-method *all* the instances of the tile-object change to the same value. Why is that?

As when I set `tile.x` everything works as expected, meaning each object gets the right value.

This is how I create the multiple instances:

In a for loop I am creating multiple instances of said object:

```
for (var y = 0; y < 10; ++y) {
  for (var x = 0; x < 10; ++x) {
    var tile = Object.create(tileProperty);
    tile.init(x, y);
    ...
  }
}
```

And this is the cloned object:

```
var tileProperty = {
    // this works
    x: null, 
    y: null,
    // this will get changed for ALL instances
    position: { 
        x: null,
        y: null
    },
    init: function(x, y) {
        this.name = x.toString() + y.toString();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.position.x = x;
        this.position.y = y;
        this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var that = this;
        $(this.canvas).bind('click', function() {
            console.log(that.position, that.x, that.y);
        });

        document.body.appendChild(this.canvas);
    }
}
```

Comment: duplicate of [Crockford's Prototypal inheritance - Issues with nested objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131052/crockfords-prototypal-inheritance-issues-with-nested-objects). See also [Why are my JS object properties being overwritten by other instances](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13127589/1048572)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are my JavaScript object properties being overwritten by other instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127589/why-are-my-javascript-object-properties-being-overwritten-by-other-instances)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
var tileProperty = {
    position: { // we will inherit from this
        x: null,
        y: null,
        init: function(x, y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    },
    init: function(x, y) {
        this.name = x.toString() + y.toString();
        // create an own Position object for each instance
        this.position = Object.create(this.position);
        // and initialize it
        this.position.init(x, y); // you might inline this invocation of course
        …
    },
    …
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're having a reference to the same `position` object in all your objects.

What you should do is using the [standard prototype solution](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model) :

```
function tileProperty() {
    this.position = { 
        x: null,
        y: null
    };
}
tileProperty.prototype.init = function(x, y) {
    this.name = x.toString() + y.toString();
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.position.x = x;
    this.position.y = y;
    this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var that = this;
    $(this.canvas).bind('click', function() {
        console.log(that.position, that.x, that.y);
    });

    document.body.appendChild(this.canvas);
}
```

and then build your instance using

```
var tp = new tileProperty();
```

Comment: If you are using a constructor (should be capitalized, btw), you would not use a `init` method