# Javascript Constant Setting Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

When running this code, the whatever value is first passed in with the constructor `Test(callbacks)` becomes the callback that is always called, even in later instantiations of `Test`

```
function Test(callbacks) {
    if (callbacks) {
        if (callbacks.callback) {
            this.callback = callbacks.callback;
        }
    }

    this.options.complete = $.proxy(this.options.complete, this);
}

Test.prototype = {
    options: {
        type: "GET",
        complete: function() {
            this.callback();
        }
    },
    callback: function() { console.log("OVERRIDE ME"); },

    execute: function() {
        $.ajax(this.options);
    }
};

var eins = {callback: function() {console.log("AAA");}};
var zwei = {callback: function() {console.log("BBB");}};

var A = new Test(eins);
var B = new Test(zwei);

A.execute();
B.execute();
```

Running this code, every time you will get the output `AAA`. How does `function() {console.log("AAA");}` become a constant value for the prototype?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Crockford's Prototypal inheritance - Issues with nested objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131052/crockfords-prototypal-inheritance-issues-with-nested-objects) or [Why are my JS object properties being overwritten by other instances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127589/why-are-my-js-object-properties-being-overwritten-by-other-instances)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all starts with this line:

```
this.callback = callbacks.callback;
```

When you make a call `new Test(eins)`, `eins` comes in as the `callbacks` argument.  That line then sets `this.callback` (ie. the "callback" property on your new instance of Test) to the callback property of `callbacks`, ie. of `eins`.

Now, that alone wouldn't affect B.  However, there's something tricky:

```
this.options.complete = $.proxy(this.options.complete, this);
```

You would think that that would set the "options" property on your Test instance, right?  Wrong.  The way Javascript works is that if a property isn't defined on your instance (eg. you didn't do `this.options = something`) then Javascript will look up the "prototype chain", where it will find the prototype's "options", and set it (not your instance's "options", since your instance doesn't have one).

You can fix all this by changing that line to:

```
this.options = {complete: $.proxy(this.options.complete, this)};
```

but of course that would lose your `type: "GET",` so either you need to do:

```
this.options = {type: "GET", complete: $.proxy(this.options.complete, this)};
```

or you need to base your options off the prototype's:

```
this.options = {};
for (var key in this.prototype.options) {
    this.options[key] = this.prototype.options[key];
}
this.options.complete = $.proxy(this.options.complete, this);
```

If you happen to be using the (excellent) Underscore library, it even has an `extend` function for doing this sort of thing more easily:

```
this.options = _.extend({}, this.prototype.options,
                        {complete: $.proxy(this.options.complete, this)});
```

Or (depending on your style preferences):

```
this.options = _.extend({}, this.prototype.options);
this.options.complete = $.proxy(this.options.complete, this);
```

Incidentally, Underscore also has a `_.bind` method which is comparable to jQuery's "proxy",  so you could also do:

```
this.options = _.extend({}, this.prototype.options);
this.options.complete = _.bind(this.options.complete, this);
```

Comment: I never said it wasn't :-) The question was "How does function() {console.log("AAA");} become a constant value for the prototype?", and the answer is that it happens in that line.

Comment: FWIW, jQuery also has [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/), but I do agree, Underscore is a nice library. Luckily, OO JS is not too much of a common thing for me.

Comment: There's some subtle difference between the jQuery extend and the Underscore one, but I couldn't remember what that difference was so I stuck to Underscore's in my example.  But yeah, you can totally use jQuery's too.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
    this.options.complete = $.proxy(this.options.complete, this);
```

You're replacing the `options.complete` function of the prototype by one that will always have `this` as context.

The problem is that you don't have a `this.options` object proper to `this`, but only one shared with all objects having the same prototype.