# Achieving member variable inheritance in JavaScript using "pseudoclassical" pattern

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

In <JavaScript: The Good Parts>, Douglas introduced the so called "pseudoclassical" pattern as one of the way to achieve inheritance. However, it seems the example he gives can not achieve inheritance of member variables, since prototype inheritance will not create copies of "superclass" variables when the "subclass" is constructed.

For a concrete example, let's consider two classes: a **InputStream** class that handles a underlying input mechanism as well as provides a simple **read** interface to read byte by byte; and a **Utf8InputStream** class that inherits **InputStream** and provide a **readUtf8** interface to read a valid UTF8 character. It then seems problematic under the "pseudoclassical" pattern as all the Utf8InputStream will share the same underlying InputStream and things will obviously break.

It seems to me that using composition instead of inheritance will easily solve the problem, but just out of curiosity, is there anyway to achieve the inheritance of member variables here?

Comment: Might be helpful: The same Doug talking about power constructor and inheritance - @25min 10sec: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DwYPG6vreJg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It then seems problematic under the "pseudoclassical" pattern as all the Utf8InputStream will share the same underlying InputStream and things will obviously break.

No, that just happens when you're doing it wrong and [create an instance for the prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592913/what-is-the-reason-to-use-the-new-keyword-here/12593049#12593049). [Correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13127794/1048572):

```
function Utf8InputStream(…) {
    InputStream.call(this, …);
    …
}
Utf8InputStream.prototype = Object.create(InputStream.prototype);
```