# JavaScript and prototype inheritance

Tags: javascript

It seems as though I am finally understanding JavaScript inheritance and how it should be done properly.  Here is my code:

```
function Human(eyes) {
    this.eyes = eyes ? "Not blind" : "Blind";
}
Human.prototype.canSee = function () {
    return this.eyes;
};
function Male(name, eyes) {
    Human.call(this, eyes);
    this.name = name;
}
Male.prototype = Object.create(Human.prototype);
var Sethen = new Male("Sethen", true);
console.log(Sethen.canSee()); //logs "Not blind"
```

From what I understand, using `Object.create` to create your prototype object for inheritance is much better than using the `new` keyword.  This raises a couple questions in my head.

1. In the `Male.prototype = Object.create(Human.prototype)` would the prototype chain be `Male.prototype --> Human.prototype --> Object.prototype --> null`?
2. In the `Male` constructor where I use `Human.call(this, eyes);` to call a super class, I have to pass eyes again in the `Male` constructor to pass it to the `Human` constructor.  This seems like a pain, is there an easier way to do this?
3. How come sometimes I see code like `Male.prototype = new Human();` ... This seems to be incorrect.  What is actually happening when we do that??

Comment: Have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040684/javascript-inheritance-object-create-vs-new and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166616/understanding-the-difference-between-object-create-and-new-somefunction-in-j ???

Comment: No I haven't.  I will take a look though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. That's correct. When you set `Male.prototype = Object.create(Human.prototype)` you set the prototype chain as `Male.prototype --> Human.prototype --> Object.prototype --> null`. Then when you create `var Sethen = new Male` the instance (`Sethen`) inherits from this prototype chain.
2. No, you need to manually pass the parameters to the base constructor function. If you want to could set `this.eyes = eyes ? "Not blind" : "Blind"` within the `Male` function itself but that would just be code duplication. What you're doing is correct.
3. That was the old way of doing things (before `Object.create` was standardized). I would recommend that you don't use it. For most cases it's the same as the new method. However using this method you also get unwanted properties like `eyes` on `Male.prototype`.

When we do `Male.prototype = new Human` we create a new instance of `Human` and assign it to `Male.prototype`. Hence the prototype chain is `Male.prototype --> Human.prototype --> Object.prototype --> null`. However we also get the property `Male.prototype.eyes` which we don't require. That should only belong to the instance of `Male`.

I would recommend you read my blog post. It's a really good primer on prototypal inheritance: [Aadit M Shah | Why Prototypal Inheritance Matters](http://aaditmshah.github.io/why-prototypal-inheritance-matters/)

Comment: Thanks man!  This cleared up things for me.  I assumed that we were getting some unwanted properties like `eyes` as well, but wasn't sure.

Comment: Before Object.create helper functions were used: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711 (still are if you want to support IE 8) In these helper functions the constructor can be set to the right function after setting inheritance as well. You still need to do this if you're planning to use the `constructor` property.

Comment: @HMR Ah. Well, the only helper function I use nowadays is [`augment`](https://github.com/javascript/augment). It uses `Object.create` but you can implement it without using `Object.create` as well.