# Override this.method = function() inside of a var x = function()

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

I have a Javascript Object:

```
var Dog = function() {
    this.speak = function() {
        return 'woof'
    }
    this.trick = function() {
        return 'sitting' 
    }
}
```

I want to make a new object, Cat, that is based on Dog but has a different `speak` method:

```
var Cat = ???
    ...
    this.speak = function() {
        return 'meow'
    }
    ...
```

So I can ultimately do this:

```
var tabby = new Cat();

tabby.speak() //returns 'meow'
tabby.trick() //returns 'sitting'
```

I have little experience with 'object-oriented Javascript' and can't seem to find an example online that reflects what I want to do, nor do I know what keywords to search for.

I thought it would be something similar to how I override functions in Backbone, but this seems different:

```
var Cat = Dog.extend({
    //the speak function below would override the one that returns 'woof'
    speak: function() {
        return 'meow'
    }
});
```

Any help is appreciated!

(Above is the simplified version of my ultimate goal - I want to override the `render` method inside of [Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.X](https://github.com/shutterstock/rickshaw/blob/master/src/js/Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.X.js))

Comment: Check tutorials on how to use prototypes and inheritance in JS.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/17730683/218196 to get an idea how to do prototypal inheritance. Also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_Revisited

Comment: A basic introduction to JavaScript prototype and constructor functions can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually in JavaScript, we'll define methods on a prototype, instead on the instance:

```
function Dog() {}
Dog.prototype.speak = function () {
    return 'woof';
};
Dog.prototype.trick = function () {
    return 'sitting';
};
```

The difference between defining a method on a prototype and on the instance is that prototypes allow you to share properties between all objects that have their prototype set to the same object. This object is where you define what properties are shared, and a prototype object can also have its own prototype, creating a prototype chain.

To create a simple example, let's take a look at a simple example:

```
var foo = { bar: 1 };

// create a new object with its prototype set to `foo`
var baz = Object.create(foo);

console.log(foo.bar); // 1
console.log(baz.bar); // 1

// prototype properties and values are shared
foo.bar = 2;

console.log(foo.bar); // 2
console.log(baz.bar); // 2

// this is an instance property, so the property is no longer shared
baz.bar = 3; 

console.log(foo.bar); // 2
console.log(baz.bar); // 3
```

If you have a prototypal-inheritance system in place, this is what you'd do:

```
function Dog() {}
Dog.prototype.speak = function () {
    return 'woof';
};
Dog.prototype.trick = function () {
    return 'sitting';
};

function Cat() {}
Cat.prototype = Object.create(Dog.prototype);
Cat.prototype.constructor = Cat;
Cat.prototype.speak = function () {
    return 'meow';
};
```

Remember that if you define a property on an instance, it will override the property set on the prototype, the prototype's prototype, and so on.

---

If you're looking for an answer to your specific situation where you have the methods defined on an instance (and it isn't a built-in constructor -- some have special behaviour), you need to do something a bit different:

```
function Cat() {
    Dog.call(this);
    this.speak = function () {
        return 'meow';
    };
}
```

What this does is it gives the `Dog` function the current object of the instance of `Cat`, on which it can set properties on. This is done by setting the value of `this` in `Dog` to the instance of `Cat`, just for that call using `func.call(/* value of this */);`.

Answer (score 2):

Given your current approach, you could do this:

```
var Dog = function() {
    this.speak = function() {
        return 'woof'
    }
    this.trick = function() {
        return 'sitting' 
    }
}

var Cat = function() {
    Dog.call(this)

    this.speak = function() {
        return 'meow'
    }
}
```

Though we're not using prototypal inheritance here. We're just assigning own properties directly to the objects. This is less efficient than using shared, inherited methods. Not to mention that the `Cat` creates the `speak` method on the `Dog`, then overwrites it immediately.

```
var tabby = new Cat();

tabby.speak() //returns 'meow'
tabby.trick() //returns 'sitting'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function Dog() {}

Dog.prototype.speak = function() {
  return 'woof';
};

Dog.prototype.trick = function() {
  return 'sitting';
};

function Cat(){}

Cat.prototype = Object.create(Dog.prototype);

Cat.prototype.speak = function() {
  return 'meow';
};

var fluffy = new Cat();

fluffy.speak(); // 'meow'
fluffy.trick(); // 'sitting'
```

Basically, you want to do some Googling for "prototypal inheritance".

Answer (score 1):

Same concept as the other answers but here is the javascript secret inherits function *slightly simplified* from google closure - https://code.google.com/p/closure-library/source/browse/closure/goog/base.js#1578

```
 var inherits = function(child, parent) {
    function tmp () {};
    tmp.prototype = parent.prototype;
    child.superClass_ = parent.prototype;
    child.prototype = new tmp;
    child.prototype.constructor = child;
  };
```

Now you can

```
var Dog = function() {};
Dog.prototype.speak = function(){
    return 'woof';
}
Dog.prototype.trick = function(){
  return 'sitting';   
}

var Cat = function(){};
inherits(Cat, Dog); //weird
Cat.prototype.speak = function(){
        return "meow";
};


var HouseCat = function(){};
inherits(HouseCat, Cat);
HouseCat.prototype.speak = function(){
   return "purr";
};


var dog = new Dog();
var cat = new Cat();
var houseCat = new HouseCat();


console.log(dog.speak());  //woof
console.log(cat.speak());  //meow
console.log(houseCat.speak());  //purr
console.log(houseCat.trick());  //sitting
console.log(cat instanceof Dog);  //true
console.log(houseCat instanceof Cat);  //true
console.log(houseCat instanceof Dog);  //true
console.log(dog instanceof Cat);  //false
console.log(cat instanceof HouseCat);  //false
```