# Check if instance has inherited function in prototype chain

Tags: javascript, prototype, instance

If I have an inheritance method set up like this:

```
function A() {}


function B() {
    A.call(this,{});
}

B.prototype = Object.create(A);
B.prototype.constructor = B;

function C() {
    B.call(this, {});
}

C.prototype = Object.create(B);
C.prototype.constructor = C;


var a = new A();
var b = new B();
var c = new C();
```

Is it possible to confirm, that the instance `c` has `A` in it's prototype chain, or has the information been lost somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

No !!!. In your example

```
C.prototype = Object.create(C);
C.prototype.constructor = C;
```

You have a prototype of `C` instances set to `C`

If you change to `C.prototype = Object.create(B);`

you will see this

[image]

But this doesn't mean that your **c is instanceof A**. Why ?
Because you have set the **prototype** to an **Function** not to an **Object**

If you will change your code to this, that its prototype will be an object

```
function A() {}


function B() {
    A.call(this,{});
}

B.prototype = Object.create(new A());
B.prototype.constructor = B;

function C() {
    B.call(this, {});
}

C.prototype = Object.create(new B());
C.prototype.constructor = C;


var a = new A();
var b = new B();
var c = new C();
```

In this case your c has A in it's prototype chain.

You can test it with `c instanceof B` and `c instanceof A` in the console

[image]

Comment: Try `console.log(c instanceof A)`

Comment: @thefourtheye don't hurry

Comment: What if `A` or `B` accepts a parameter? How would you establish the prototype chain?

Comment: @thefourtheye what is the problem in parameters?

Comment: Sorry the C.prototype = Object.create(C) was a typo. Thanks for the answer, I'll try it out!

Comment: This is not the correct way to fix this. Let me find a dupe.

Comment: See if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22316035/1903116) helps and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17393153/1903116)

Comment: @thefourtheye Thanks! So using Object.create(F.prototype) vs Object.create(new F()) is better because it creates less objects?