# Property inheritance in Javascript

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I have the following functions which define an inheritance chain.

```
function Person(name,age) {

    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

Person.prototype.dance = function () {
    console.log("Person is dancing");
};

var Programmer = function (name, age, skills)
{   
    Programmer.prototype = new Person(name, age);;
    this.skills = skills;
};



Programmer.prototype.talkShit = function () {
    console.log("The programmer " + this.name+ " is talking shit....");
};
```

and I try to call **dance()** method on a programmer object

```
  var programmerX = new Programmer("Pro A", 30, "Talking crap");

        programmerX.dance();
```

However, an error happened saying that dance() is **undefined**. I'm just wondering why? What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend your Object prototype with

```
Programmer.prototype = new Person();
Programmer.prototype.constructor = Programmer;
```

But obviously, an empty constructor will be called, so you will have to call this manually afterwards from within your Programmer object

```
Person.call(this, name, age);
```

Giving you

```
function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

Person.prototype.dance = function () {
    console.log("Person is dancing");
};

function Programmer(name, age, skills)
{
    Person.call(this, name, age);
    this.skills = skills;
};
Programmer.prototype = new Person();
Programmer.prototype.constructor = Programmer;
```

Testing this with

```
var programmerX = new Programmer("Alice", 30, "Something");
var programmerY = new Programmer("Bob", 25, "Something else");
console.log(programmerX);
console.log(programmerY);
programmerX.dance();
```

We'll get

```
{ name: 'Alice', age: 30, skills: 'Something' }
{ name: 'Bob', age: 25, skills: 'Something else' }
Person is dancing
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple issues with how you're defining the prototype inheritance chain. You want to assign the `Programmer` prototype outside of the constructor and you'll likely want to be using `Object.create` instead of `new`. You also want to call the "super" constructor in your `Programmer` constructor by calling `Person.call(this, name, age)`. I'd recommend an approach like this:

```
function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

Person.prototype.dance = function() {
    console.log("Person is dancing");
};

var Programmer = function(name, age, skills) {   
    Person.call(this, name, age);
    this.skills = skills;
};

Programmer.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Programmer.constructor = Programmer;

Programmer.prototype.talkShit = function () {
    console.log("The programmer " + this.name+ " is talking shit....");
};
```

Comment: For additional information as to choosing between `Object.create` vs `new`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040684/javascript-inheritance-object-create-vs-new

Answer (score 1):

I just want to point out how easy this is in TypeScript:

```
class Person {
    constructor(public name: string, public age: number) {
    }
    dance() {
        console.log('Person is dancing');
    }
}

class Programmer extends Person {
    constructor(name: string, age: number, public skills: string) {
        super(name, age);
    }
    talkShit() {
        console.log('The programmer ' + this.name + 'is talking shit....');
    }
}

var programmerX = new Programmer('Pro A', 30, 'Talking crap');
```

Which generates the JavaScript for you, which you can see on [The TypeScript Playground here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=class%20Person%20%7B%0A%09constructor%28public%20name%3A%20string%2C%20public%20age%3A%20number%29%20%7B%0A%09%7D%0A%09dance%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09console.log%28%27Person%20is%20dancing%27%29%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Programmer%20extends%20Person%20%7B%0A%09constructor%28name%2C%20age%2C%20public%20skills%3A%20string%29%20%7B%0A%09%09super%28name%2C%20age%29%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%09talkShit%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09console.log%28%27The%20programmer%20%27%20%2B%20this.name%20%2B%20%27is%20talking%20shit....%27%29%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20programmerX%20%3D%20new%20Programmer%28%27Pro%20A%27%2C%2030%2C%20%27Talking%20crap%27%29%3B%0A%0A).

If you're going to be doing a lot of inheritance, it'll make your code a lot more readable.

Comment: Thanks but I wanted to figure out what was wrong with my code.