# Why use Object.create instead of new Super while assigning DerivedClass.prototype

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I've been reading MDN guide on Object Oriented programming with Javascript where in an example to show Inheritance, the following is mentioned:

```
// Create a Student.prototype object that inherits from Person.prototype.
// Note: A common error here is to use "new Person()" to create the
// Student.prototype. That's incorrect for several reasons, not least 
// that we don't have anything to give Person for the "firstName" 
// argument. The correct place to call Person is above, where we call 
// it from Student.
Student.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype); // See note below
```

I've looked into other answers as well, but they don't specifically tell what problems one will face on using `Student.prototype = new Person()`

One problem mentioned above concerns with passing `firstName`, but that's just one scenario.

Before anyone marks this as duplicate. The question here [Using "Object.create" instead of "new"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709612/using-object-create-instead-of-new) deals with generally using `Object.create` instead of constructors and not with what I'm asking.

The question here [What is the reason to use the 'new' keyword at Derived.prototype = new Base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592913/what-is-the-reason-to-use-the-new-keyword-at-derived-prototype-new-base/12593269#12593269) deals with difference between `foo()` and `new foo()`

One answer for this question [JavaScript inheritance: Object.create vs new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040684/javascript-inheritance-object-create-vs-new) gives one more reason:

> When SomeBaseClass has a function body, this would get executed with
>   the new keyword. This usually is not intended - you only want to set
>   up the prototype chain. In some cases it even could cause serious
>   issues because you actually instantiate an object, whose
>   private-scoped variables are shared by all MyClass instances as they
>   inherit the same privileged methods. Other side effects are
>   imaginable.
>
> So, you should generally prefer Object.create. Yet, it is not
>   supported in some legacy browsers; which is the reason you see the
>   new-approach much too frequent as it often does no (obvious) harm.
>   Also have a look at this answer.

Reading the above it seems it depends more on the given scenario being tackled. Is there a stringent reason for MDN saying using `new SuperClass()` is incorrect?

Comment: Depends on your definition of "incorrect". I can't think of a situation where it would be useful, and as others have pointed out there are several reasons why it's problematic. What is your question exactly? Why are you worried about this?

Comment: I'm not worried about it. It's just that most of the JavaScript code that I've seen uses the `new Parent()`.  I could see where `Object.create` would be more useful but it doesn't feel right to say the former is plain right incorrect.

Comment: @KartikAnand: The `new Person` way is usually used by people who haven't really thought it through. It was used in simple code early on and became established, even though it's a real pain to do right. It *can* be correct, it's just over-complicated in the general case. So when we'd progressed a bit further, we realized there was a better way. I've explained that more thoroughly in my updated answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Benefits of using `Object.create` for inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17392857/1048572)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR** You *could* use `new Person` to build your `Student.prototype`, but doing so complicates all of your constructor functions, limits their ability to detect construction errors, and requires that *all* constructors everywhere handle that form of use. Since it's more complicated, error-prone, and limiting, most people have gone the other way: `Object.create`.

The main pragmatic issue is: What if the super constructor requires arguments? Say `Person` requires a name:

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

How am I to use `new Person` to create my prototype? I have no `name` to provide it.

Now, there are two ways to solve this:

1. Require that all constructors that need arguments detect that they have been called without arguments, *assume* they're being called to build a prototype, and handle that case correctly.
2. Use `Object.create` instead.

Here's the first way:

```
// NOT WHAT MOST PEOPLE DO
function Person(name) {
    if (arguments.length === 0) {
        return;
    }
    this.name = name;
}
function Student(name) {
    Person.call(this, name);
}
Student.prototype = new Person;
Student.prototype.constructor = Student;
```

Note how `Person` has to detect that it's being called with no arguments, hope that that's because it's being used to create a prototype rather than for some other reason, and avoid trying to use the missing arguments.

That's error-prone and awkward, and it means that `Person` can't (for instance) raise an error if it doesn't receive `name` for the final instance construction call. It just doesn't know why it's being called, so it can't tell whether not having `name` is correct or not.

So most people go the other way:

```
// What most people do
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
function Student(name) {
    Person.call(this, name);
}
Student.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Student.prototype.constructor = Student;
```

`Person` doesn't have to have any special-case code in it, and is free to raise an error if it doesn't get `name` and needs it.

That's sufficienly ingrained now, as well, that it's baked into ES2015 (aka ES6)'s `class` keyword. This ES2015 code:

```
class Student extends Person {
    constructor(name) {
        super(name);
    }
}
```

Translates fairly closely to the `Object.create` ES5 code above. (Not exactly, but fairly closely.)