# How to inherit using Object.create()

Tags: javascript

I created an instance of Shape using Object.create() method and tried accessing the property of Shape as follows, but the inherited property becomes `undefined`:

```
    function Shape(){
      this.x = 10;
      this.y = 20;
    }

    var rectangle = Object.create(Shape);

    console.log(rectangle.x) // undefined
```

Comment: [Here's another question which might provide some insight and possible alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040684/javascript-inheritance-object-create-vs-new)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript inheritance: Object.create vs new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040684/javascript-inheritance-object-create-vs-new)

Comment: Your question title is asking about inheritance, but your question body is about making an instance. These are two different things.

Comment: @Mark_M Don't we make instance to inherit from parent objects?

Answer (score 2):

To create an instance of a constructor, use `new`

```
var rectangle = new Shape()
```

Comment: Shouldn't we use `Object.create()` to create an instance of a constructor?

Answer (score 0):

May declare the `shape` as an object instead of `function` though functions are first class object in js. Create a function inside this object and return the required value from this function

```js
var shape = {
  userProperty: function(x, y) {
    this.x = x || 10; // if no value of x is passed it will be 10
    this.y = y || 10; // if no value of y is passed it will be 10
    return {
      x: this.x,
      y: this.y
    }
  }
}
var rectangle = Object.create(shape);
console.log(rectangle.userProperty(40).x) // 40
```