# "new" operator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, constructor

I'm trying to understand the `new` operator. Have a look at the following function:

```
var _new = function(fn) {
    var obj = Object.create(fn.prototype);
    fn.apply(obj);
    obj.constructor = fn; // <--- EDIT: unnecessary
    return obj;
};
```

which can be applied like that:

```
var Test = function(){
    this.foo = 1;
};

var instance = _new(Test);
```

Of course it can be easily extended to arbitrary number of arguments (I'm just trying to keep it simple).

It seems that it works like `new` keyword. So what is the difference if any? What else `new` operator does to an object?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166616/understanding-the-difference-between-object-create-and-new-somefunction-in-j

Comment: `constructor` is actually a property of `fn.prototype`, not the instance itself.

Comment: @FelixKling Oh, really? I didn't know that. That makes the code even simplier.

Comment: @Bergi Yep, it's a duplicate (missed that one). Apparently I can vote to close my own question. Nice. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, this is basically what `new` is doing: Create a new object that inherits from `Func.prototype` and call `Func` with `this` referring to this new object.

There is a slight difference to your implementation though: If the constructor (`Func`) does *not* return an object, `this` is *implicitly* returned. *If* it returns an object (any object) than it will become the return value of the constructor call.

So a more accurate replication would be:

```
var _new = function(fn) {
    var obj = Object.create(fn.prototype);
    var result = fn.apply(obj);
    return result != null && typeof result === 'object' ? result : obj;
};
```

That's it. You can see it as syntactic sugar if you want to, just like the conditional operator.

---

Some pointers to the reference: When `new` is used, the internal `[[Construct]]` function of the constructor is called. What exactly happens is described in [section 13.2.2](http://es5.github.com/#x13.2.2) of the specification and it pretty much does the same as the function you (and I) wrote.

The point I'm not completely sure about is that the object's internal `[[Extensible]]` property is set to `true`. I would assume that every object you create via `Object.create` is extensible by default (if it's prototype is extensible).

Comment: Oh, wow. That's an interesting feature. I've always thought that it doesn't matter what constructor returns. I've never checked that though. :) Thank you for the answer!

Comment: You're welcome :) Added some small remarks...

Comment: So what does it mean for an object to be extensible? Are there nonextensible objects?

Comment: Good question. The specification says *"If true, own properties may be added to the object."*. It seems to be related to the [`Object.freeze`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.3.9), though I don't know if that's the only place where it's used (searching for `[[Extensible]]` on the page might provide more info).

Comment: @freakish: [`Object.preventExtensions({})`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/preventExtensions) (`.freeze()` and `.seal()` do similar things)

Comment: Wow, just when I thought I know quite a lot about JavaScript. Thank you, guys, for help. :)