# Bug while Create multiple instances of an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, constructor

I want to create multiple instances of an object in Javascript. I know that using `Object.create(obj)` or using `new ObjConstructor();` or `using ObjFactory();` (thanks to @WiktorZychla) will let me create different instances.

I understand the differences from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166616/understanding-the-difference-between-object-create-and-new-somefunction-in-j), and both of them do work when the Object Constructor is coded in a certain way.

However when I use return in my object <strike>constructor</strike> factory to implement private variables using closure, the two instances created seem to be the same.

This is my object constructor function:

```
var obj3 = function () {

    variable3 = "Hello World";
    function3_private = function () {

        return variable3;
    };

    return {

        function3_get : function () {

            return variable3;
        },

        function3_set : function (v) {

            variable3 = v;
        },

        function3_print : function () {

            return function3_private();
        }
    };

};
```

How do I use this constructor to create two different instances? Or should I make changes in the constructor to achieve the same?

Please suggest best practices if my code is not following any. 
Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GcD9n/

Comment: What you have is **not** a constructor! It is a factory method. Just call it without `new`.

Comment: variable3 is global variable since you didnt use var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your private variables are actually global, because you've missed out the keyword `var`. This means that any objects you make are all using and modifying the same instance of `variable3` and `function3_private`, and calling

```
function3_private();
```

works and prints out the value of `variable3`.

Comment: Thanks. Adding the var keyword stopped function3_set() from working. The output isn't as I would want. Can you try working with the fiddle?

Comment: @srrvnn I added var in front of both `variable3` and `function3_private` in the fiddle and it works fine for me. What is `function3_set` now doing for you?

Comment: It works! I didn't add the var for function3_private(), the previous time.