# Object.create in javascript : why does my code outputs Object instead of name string value

Tags: javascript, node.js

I tested this snippet and execute with node.js

```
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}


john = Object.create(Person);
john.name = 'John';
console.log(john.name);
```

It returns Person. Why doesn't it return 'John' ?

Update: my question is not about new vs create, I know perfectly how new and create should be used. My question is why I cannot set name property value as usual.

Comment: FYI If you replace `john = Object.create(Person);` with `john = new Person;` you will get the expected result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding the difference between Object.create() and new SomeFunction() in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166616/understanding-the-difference-between-object-create-and-new-somefunction-in-j)

Comment: @Popnoodles I know new, my question is not about new vs create, it's why I cannot overload name property as usual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It returns `Person`. Why doesn't it return `'John'` ?

Because that `Object.create` line creates an object with the `Person` function as its prototype, and the `Person` function object has a surprising definition of the `name` property that prevents your writing to it. (The definition makes sense once you know about it, but it's surprising at first.)

What you're creating when you do

```
john = Object.create(Person);
```

...is an object that uses the `Person` function as its underlying prototype. This doesn't create a `Person` *instance* (which would use `Person.prototype` as its prototype), it creates an object that actually uses the function object `Person` itself as the prototype.

The `Person` function has a non-writable property called `name` which is the name of the function (this is not yet in the standard, but it will be in ES6 [currently it's defined in §9.2.11 of the [draft spec](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:specification_drafts)] and V8 does it already). Because that property is *not writable*, `john.name = 'John'` doesn't do anything. (More on non-writable properties below.)

If your goal was to create a new object with `Person.prototype` as the object's underlying prototype, you'd do:

```
john = new Person();
```

or

```
john = Object.create(Person.prototype);
```

And since `Person` accepts an argument, you'd probably do

```
john = new Person('John');
```

...rather than assigning to `name` afterward.

---

More on non-writable properties: If you haven't run into them yet, they were defined as part of the 5th edition spec a while back. Here's an example:

```
var parent = {};
Object.defineProperty(parent, "foo", {
    writable: false,
    value: "original"
});
```

The `parent` object has an non-writable property, `foo`:

```
console.log(parent.foo); // "original"
parent.foo = "bar";
console.log(parent.foo); // "original"
```

If we use `parent` as a prototype, we still can't write to `foo` even on the child object:

```
var child = Object.create(parent);
console.log(child.foo); // "original"
child.foo = "bar";
console.log(child.foo); // "original"
```

That's what's happening in your code. `parent` is `Person`, and `child` is `john`.

And just to round this out: If we wanted to create a writable property on the child at this point, we could, but just not via assignment   we'd have to use `defineProperty`:

```
Object.defineProperty(child, "foo", {
    writable: true,
    value: child.foo    // (just sets the initial value)
});
console.log(child.foo); // "original"
child.foo = "bar";
console.log(child.foo); // "bar"
```

Now `child` has its *own* property called `foo`, which shadows (hides) its prototype's `foo`, and is writable.

Comment: Great answer, didn't know about non writeable property existence. Still am surprised as I would expect it should have thrown some error when trying to write on it if was not writeable.

Comment: @user310291: Thanks! Yes, I probably should have mentioned that. In loose mode, usually this sort of thing won't throw an error. In *strict* mode, usually it does. And in fact, writing to a non-writable property in strict mode normally *does* throw an error. But if I take your program and add `"use strict";` at the top (and a `var` in front of `john = ...`), I still don't get an error even though an equivalent test with my `parent`/`child` example *does* throw an error. I don't know why writing to `john.name` wouldn't throw in strict mode. Strange!

Comment: @user310291: Interestingly, my `parent`/`child` example doesn't throw in strict mode in Chrome, so it must relate to the specific version of V8... Still weird that it throws in NodeJS for my `parent`/`child` example but not for the `Person` function example!