# Is it possible to use the Object.create pattern to create a CustomEvent object?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, object-create

I know you can create a `CustomEvent` like this:

```
var wordCreated = new CustomEvent(
    "newWord", 
    {
        detail: {
            word: "hola",
            translation: "hi",
        },
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true
    }
);
```

I'm wondering how to do this without using `new`, with the `Object.create` pattern?

The problem I’m not seeing a solution to is that the `CustomEvent` takes two arguments: a string specifying a name for the event, and a configuration object containing `bubbles`, `cancelable`, and `details` properties. I’m not sure how to pass both the string and the object to `Object.create`.

Ultimately I expect to be able to use this custom event in the following standard way:

```
var p = document.querySelector('p'); // a random node
p.addEventListener('newWord', function(ev){ console.log(ev) });
p.dispatchEvent(wordCreated);
```

Comment: I'm deleting my answer for now, until I get a chance to look more into it. Apologies.

Comment: Why not doing `p.dispatchEvent(wordCreated);` using the event created in your first snippet? Thats what `CustomEvent` is for. Reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I'm trying to see how to apply the `Object.create` pattern in this context. Yes, the existing pattern works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the question in your title *"Is it possible to use the Object.create pattern to create a CustomEvent object?"* is **Yes**. Now, the answer to the follow-up question *"Shall you do it that way?"* is probably **No**. As @MartinErnst pointed out, you're just going to end up re-inventing the wheel of what `new` is already doing.

The [key difference between `new` and `Object.create`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4166616/1144203) (in case you don't already know) is that `Object.create` creates an `Object` (notice the uppercase **O**) which inherits the prototype of the object specified as the first argument of `Object.create`. The `new` operator does the same thing with the additional step of invoking the constructor of the given object, before returning an instance of the specified object (notice the lowercase **o**).

So we can use `Object.create` to create an `Object` which inherits from the `CustomEvent` prototype with something like this:

```
var customEvent1 = Object.create(CustomEvent, {  
                     detail: {
                        writable:true, 
                        configurable:true, 
                        value: { word:"hola", translation:"hi" }
                      },
                      bubbles: {
                        writable:true,  
                        configurable:true, 
                        value:true 
                      },
                      cancelable:  {
                        writable:true,  
                        configurable:true, 
                        value:true 
                      },
                      type: {
                        writable:true,
                        configurable:true,
                        value:'newWord'
                      }
                    });
```

But doing a `console.log(customEvent1)` will yield an `Object`.

Contrast this to:

```
var customEvent2 = new CustomEvent("newWord", { 
                     detail: {
                      word: "hola",
                      translation: "hi",
                     },
                     bubbles: true,
                     cancelable: true
                   });
```

You will see that running `console.log(customEvent2);` will yield an instance of `CustomEvent`.

So when you try to invoke `addEventListener()` and `dispatchEvent()` on the above `customEvent1` object, it will fail because that is an `Object`, not an `Event`. There are a few more things steps you will need to do to convert `customEvent1` into a full `Event` object, which is essentially what `new CustomEvent()` is already doing.

Fiddle available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ivan_sim/p56wzsqc/).

Comment: `CustomEvent.prototype` is non-configurable and non-writable so you can't redefine it that way. It results in `myCustomObject` having all configurable properties (*type* included) undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be something like:

```
obj.addEventListener("newWord", function(e) {alert(e.detail);});

var wordCreated = Object.create(CustomEvent.prototype, {
  "newWord": 
    {
        detail: {
            word: "hola",
            translation: "hi",
        },
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, indeed. Replacing the coma with a colon remove the syntax error. Still I don't know if this could work. I'm investigating. I like this question.

Comment: The isim's answer is the right way to do it. My upvote for him. I will mark this question as favorite, because I'm going to use this approach soon.

Comment: I don't get what was wrong with isim's code. It was working fine on the fiddle.

Comment: @Verhaeren I have updated my answer with why calling `dispatchEvent()` on `CustomEvent` objects created with `Object.create()` will fail.

Comment: The second argument to `Object.create` needs to be a property descriptors object.