# inherit from prototype vs inherit from constructor

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I was searching about more for `Object.create`. I have found a [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166616/understanding-the-difference-between-object-create-and-new-somefunction-in-j) question already asked by users. In accepted answer they are talking about inheritance like

`Object.create` builds an object that inherits directly from the one passed as its first argument.

```
var o = new SomeConstructor();
```

In the above example, o inherits directly from `SomeConstructor.prototype`

Now I just want to know what is the mean of inherits from `prototype` and how it make difference practically from inherit directly from constructor

Comment: You almost never in herit directly from a constructor. It would be very unusual to do `var o = Object.create(SomeConstructor);`. More likely you'd do `var o = Object.create(SomeConstructor.prototype)`, which would be generally equivalent to `var o = new SomeConstructor();`

Comment: I have fiddle with both the method but one is printing undefined in console. http://jsfiddle.net/3hdvuebh/3/

Comment: You might want to read [this doc page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

Comment: Here - http://jsfiddle.net/3hdvuebh/4/ - I have fixed your fiddle (added `a.apply`). If you are creating new object without calling its constructor, of course that the logic (e.g. initializing a property) inside that constructor won't be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Explanation of Object.create***

When you do something like this:

```
var obj = Object.create( baseMethods );

obj.ownMethod = function () {
  console.log( 'baz' );
};

var baseMethods = {
  method1: function () {
    console.log( 'something' );
  },
  method2: function () {
    console.log( 'foobar' );
  }
};
```

The object `obj` **delegates** to the `baseMethod` object whenever the JavaScript engine can't find a property on `obj`. For example, if you invoke:

```
obj.method1(); // will log 'something'
```

The JavaScript engine will first try to look up the property on `obj`. Since the property can't be found on `obj`, it will **delegate** the lookup to its **prototype object** (which we've defined using `Object.create`). In this case, the prototype object is `baseMethod`. Now that the property has been found, the engine will execute `method1`.

***Explanation of Constructor.prototype***

In your code, you have:

```
var o = new SomeConstructor();
```

Think of `SomeConstructor` as having an object similar to my `baseMethods` object where instances of SomeConstructor will first look up properties on the instance itself and then **delegate** to that object if the property can't be found. In your example, it just so happens that the object that instances of `SomeConstructor` will delegate to is `SomeConstructor.prototype`.

Looking at your question, please don't make the mistake of thinking that `o` inherits from `SomeConstructor` - the correct way to think of it is that `o` **delegates** its object-lookup to an object which just so happens to be a property on the `SomeConstructor` function object (namely, `SomeConstructor.prototype`)