# Understanding the new operator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop

I was looking at the code of the `new` operator in the Douglas Crockford series.

```
function Shane(name){
    this.name = name;    
}

var sha = new Shane("name");
console.log(sha);
```

The above code just creates a new Shane object and sets its constructor to Shane and Prototype to Object.prototype:

```
function new(func, args){
     var that = Object.create(func.prototype); 
         result = func.apply(that, args);
     return (typeof result==='object' && result) || that;
}
```

Can anyone explain me on what this code does and give me an example for it?

Comment: "*Can anyone explain me on what this code does*" ... It throws a syntax error: `Unexpected token new`

Comment: @p.s.w.g: I am asking on how the function new works? I am not using the function new to construct an object.

Comment: Start with MDN: [new operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)

Comment: @p.s.w.g: I know how new works, i am not understanding the function new() on what it does?

Comment: No, neither `new` nor `new()` do anything about setting constructors.

Comment: @Shane: Well, if you know how `new` works, then you should know that `new()` just does the same things (except for constructors returning functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The above code just creates a new Shane object and sets its constructor to Shane and Prototype to Object.prototype.

Not quite.  The prototype of the object `sha` will be `Shane.prototype`.  The prototype of `Shane.prototype` will be `Object.prototype`.

The function you present (better named `new2`, `gnu`, `knew` or some other variant of `new`, since it's a syntax error as it stands) performs the same three essential actions that the `new` operator in the language does.

```
new Shane(arg1, ..., argN)
```

does these three things:

- Creates a new empty object and sets its [[Prototype]] property to Shane.prototype.
- Applies the function `Shane` and the parameters `arg1`, ... `argN` in the context of the new object, potentially receiving a return value.
- If a return value is received, return that.  If not return this newly created object.

The `new2` function (let's call it) does these same things.  So you could use it like this:

```
var sha2 = new2(Shane, ["name"]);
```

and get back something very similar to `sha` above.

Comment: return (typeof result==='object' && result) || that; when will that be returned in the function? i mean in which case.

Comment: If the constructor function has a `return` statement and returns something other than the `this` object, you'll likely follow that branch.

Comment: If its possible can you show some  code regarding that for understanding.

Comment: `var Foo = function(x) {this.a = x; return {b: x};};  var foo = new Foo(5);`  Now `foo.a` is `undefined` because the object being created during construction was discarded in favor of the object literal that was returned instead.  But `foo.b` has value `5`.  The object `{b: 5}` is assigned to `foo` and not the `this` object that was being enhanced by the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

here `new Shane("name")`is equivalent to: `new1 (Shane,['name']);`

```
function Shane(name){
        this.name = name;    
    }

var sha= new1 (Shane,['name']);
        console.log(sha);
        function new1(func, args){
            console.log(func,args);
             var that = Object.create(func.prototype);
 //creates an object based on func if func=null then created object  doesn't inherit from anything,
                 result = func.apply(that, args);//applys arguments which should be an array
             return (typeof result==='object' && result) || that;
// if result is received and is object then return result else return that which is newly created object
        }

here `Object.create` builds an object that inherits directly from the one passed as its first argument.
```

read about apply here:[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

see this post for more about `new` and `Object.create`:[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166616/understanding-the-difference-between-object-create-and-new-somefunction-in-j)