# Why do Object.create() and new Object() evaluate to different prototypes?

Tags: javascript, prototype, instantiation

Why do these 2 implementations behave differently? What exactly sets them apart when it comes to evaluating their prototypes?

**Creating an object with the prototype specified:**

```
   function Foo() {}

   // creates an object with a specified prototype
   var bar = Object.create(Foo);

   console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(bar)); // returns: function Foo(){}
   console.log(Foo.isPrototypeOf(bar)); // returns: true
```

**Creating an object with the constructor method:**

```
   function Foo() {}

   // creates an object with the constructor method    
   var bar = new Foo();

   console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(bar)); // returns: Foo {}
   console.log(Foo.isPrototypeOf(bar)); // returns: false
```

Also, why does the second implementation return both `Foo {}` and `false`?

Comment: "Also, why does the second implementation return both Foo {} and false?" is a great question. I've updated my answer to address it.

Comment: Note that you would usually do `var bar = Object.create( Foo.prototype );`, which gives you the expected behaviour.

Comment: possible duplicatet of [Understanding the difference between `Object.create()` and `new SomeFunction()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4166616/1048572)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`Object.create(Foo)` means "create an object with `Foo` as the prototype".

`new Foo()` means "Create an object with `Foo.prototype` as the prototype and `Foo` as the constructor".

Therefore `Foo` is the *prototype* of `Bar` in the first example and the *constructor* of `Bar` in the second example.

I think the second part of your question is prompted by misleading console output - `Object.getPrototypeOf(bar)` actually returns `Foo.prototype`, not `Foo`:

```
function Foo() {}
var bar = new Foo();

Object.getPrototypeOf(bar) === Foo
// -> false

Object.getPrototypeOf(bar) === Foo.prototype
// -> true
```

Answer (score 11):

When you use the 'new' keyword to instantiate an object JavaScript actually adds in two lines of code to your object.

If you intend to create an object with pseudoclassical instantiation you create your object like this:

```
var Foo = function() {
this.property = 'baz';
};
```

When you call `var bar = new Foo()` Javascript runs Foo as the following:

```
var Foo = function() {
// ADDED CODE: var this = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
this.property = 'baz';
// ADDED CODE: return this;
```

Using Object.create creates a delegation relationship from the newly created object to the specified object, so in your first case bar is delegating its lookups to Foo, but in the second case the lookups are delegated to Foo.prototype.

You may find [this](http://www.willvillanueva.com/an-introduction-to-pseudoclassical-instantiation-patterns-and-subclassing-in-javascript/) blog post interesting.  It goes into Pseudoclassical instantiation (using the new keyword) as opposed to Prototypal instantiation, which does not use the new keyword.