# What's the difference between these 2 implementations of prototypal inheritance?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

What's the difference between these 2 implementations of prototypal inheritance, and considering that we're working with 2 different "prototypes" (the prototype property that's only on functions, and the internal prototype), and how do these implementations differ in their prototype chain lookup? Also, does the first implementation (using the prototype property) rely on our use of the `new` operator?

**Assigning to a functions's `prototype` property and using the `new` operator:**

```
function foo() {}

foo.prototype.output = function(){
   console.log('inherits from Function.prototype property');
};

bar = new foo();
bar.output();
```

**Storing a function in an object literal and using the `Object.create()` method:**

```
var foo = {
  output: function(){
    console.log('inherits from the internal prototype');
  }
};

var bar = Object.create(foo);
bar.output();
```

Comment: One difference is that `Object.create` is newer, and is not supported in IE8 and below

Comment: I don't see prototypal **inheritance** in your examples.

Comment: @hindmost can you elaborate please?

Comment: I think what @hindmost means is that it's not inheritance (top-to-bottom), it's rather **delegation**. Objects rely on other objects for functionalities, not on their "ancestors" since they don't have any.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding the difference between Object.create() and new SomeFunction()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166616/understanding-the-difference-between-object-create-and-new-somefunction)

Comment: @Kyll I agree that it's actually delegation, the spec refers to this as "prototypal inheritance" however. I'd rather not get stuck on semantics.

Comment: I also use the term **inheritance**, yeah is the not inheritance in the classical sense, but JS doesn't have the classical OO model (it can be simulated though)

Comment: This is a well answered topic in SO. What would make it more clear? A diagram? An audio lecture?

Comment: @jdphenix a diagram would be great!

Comment: Kyll fetched Kyle SImpson's diagram on the topic. I'd recommend reading the whole linked chapter myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference is in the way it is used, and the dangers associated.

The first one forces you to use `new` when you want to create a new object. The syntax is fairly ugly (`SomeConstructor.prototype.method`), and it bears one major flaw: calling a constructor which adds properties (`this.name = nameParam`...) without `new` will apply the construction to the global object. The behaviour of the constructor is weird (create new object which delegates to `SomeConstructor.prototype`, then apply the constructor to the new object, then if the constructor returns something replace the object by the something). Plus, in your example, `foo` itself is not usable, you have to create a new object in order to access its functionalities.

The second one, `Object.create`, doesn't force you to use any syntoxic quirk. You don't have the global pollution risk. The object `foo` has functionalities that can already be used without creating a new object, and `bar` will simply borrow these functionalities. This kind of pattern can also make it easier to implement factories (without `new`s to replace everywhere) and object pools if needed.

[Eric Eliott talks about it very well](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/the-two-pillars-of-javascript-ee6f3281e7f3), and [Kyle Simpson wrote a whole book](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch1.md) about prototype delegation!

Now, here's how the lookup happens:

- With the constructor, the lookup is done on `Constructor.prototype` (not the *actual* internal prototype of the constructor, but its `prototype`property. If you find it confusing, congratulations, you are human). Additional properties are set in the constructor function. `foo` itself is not used for the lookup, `foo.prototype` (again, not the same as `foo.__proto__` which points to Function) is the one used for it.
- With `Object.create` the lookup is done on the object itself (`foo`). There's no `prototype` non-prototype property on the object.

There's [very funny diagrams on this page of Kyle Simpson's book](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch6.md) which explain the thing further.

More on `new` in this question: [Is JavaScript's "new" keyword considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383402/is-javascripts-new-keyword-considered-harmful/383503#383503)

Comment: @Kyll what differs as far as the "lookup" is concerned? These implementations use 2 different `prototype` objects, no?

Comment: What I'm getting at is, how does the delegation happen in these 2 implementations? How do they differ in how they trace through the prototype lookup? Can you post a simple diagram please?

Comment: Kyle Simpson did an amazing diagram, let me fetch it if I can.

Answer (score 1):

OK, first of all, in case you didn't know, `Object.create` is based upon the following pattern proposed by Douglas Crockford (read more [here](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html)):

```
function create (proto) {
  function f () {}
  f.prototype = proto;
  return new f();
}
```

Now, you must be aware that the above code does not yield the same result in case you pass `null` as parameter.
The ECMAScript algorithm for creating new objects (read more [here](http://es5.github.io/#x13.2.2)) states that if the prototype of a function is set to `null` (or any non object), when you're trying to use `new f()` syntax, the newly created object will inherit from `Object.prototype`.
If you use `Object.create(null)`, the newly created object will have its `[[Prototype]]` internal member set to `null`, which means the prototype chain will stop there (your object doesn't get `hasOwnProperty` and other stuff from `Object.prototype` as normal object would).

```
var o1 = create(null);
var o2 = Object.create(null);
Object.getPrototypeOf(o1) === Object.prototype // true
Object.getPrototypeOf(o2) === Object.prototype // false
Object.getPrototypeOf(o2) === null // true
```

Answer (score -1):

The first example - foo, is a function.

The second example - foo is an object.

in the second example, bar becomes an new instance without a constructor.
See - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create, to add the constructor.

As a side note, it common best practice that constructors should begin with a capital letter.