# Why is Node's Object.create(foo) much slower than new Foo()?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wrote a simple Sudoku solver using backtracking in JS. In effort to be "purely functional" all my 9x9 puzzle arrays are immutable thus a new array is created whenever a new number is inserted.

### Version 1 using `new SudokuPuzzle`

In the first version I use the `new Puzzle(puzzle)` approach to clone the object:

```
function SudokuPuzzle(obj) {
   if (obj instanceof SudokuPuzzle) {
      this.grid = obj.grid.slice(0);  // copy array
   } // ...
}
```

Then whenever I update the array I do the following:

```
SudokuPuzzle.prototype.update = function(row, col, num) {
    var puzzle = new SudokuPuzzle(this); // clone puzzle
    puzzle.grid[row*9 + col] = num;      // mutate clone
    return puzzle;                       // return clone
}
```

### Version 2 using `Object.create()`

I wrote another version where I use `Object.create()` instead and have a base object `sudokuPuzzle` that I inherit from to create new puzzles. Here is the `clone()` method:

```
sudokuPuzzle.clone = function() {
   var puzzle = Object.create(this); // create puzzle from sudokuPuzzle
   puzzle.grid = this.grid.slice(0); // copy array
   return puzzle;                    // return newly minted puzzle
}
```

My update method in this case is

```
sudokuPuzzle.update = function(row, col, num) {
   var puzzle = this.clone();       // clone puzzle
   puzzle.grid[row*9 + col] = num;  // mutate clone
   return puzzle;                   // return clone
}
```

### Speed Tests

The first version using `new` is very fast using Node:

```
$ time node Sudoku.js
real    0m0.720s
user    0m0.699s
sys     0m0.016s
```

The second version using `Object.create()` is consistently over 10x slower:

```
$ time node Sudoku2.js
real        0m7.746s
user        0m7.647s
sys         0m0.091s
```

A [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34480709/why-is-object-create-so-much-slower-than-a-constructor) noted that `Object.create()` is a lot slower in browsers, while I am also seeing a large disparity with [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) as well. I can certainly see timing discrepancies between JS engines, but a > 10x difference?!? Does anyone know why the difference is over an *order of magnitude?!*

You can find the [source code](https://github.com/wcochran/Functional-Sudoku-Solver) here.

### Update with Annotated Answer

Thanks to Bergi's answer below I changed the line in the `clone` method from

```
 var puzzle = Object.create(this);
```

to this:

```
 var puzzle = Object.create(sudokuPuzzle);
```

which avoids long and complex inheritance chains (i.e., I always inherit from the same base object) and I now get speed results comparable to using `new`. Thanks Bergi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've already established that V8 fails to optimise `Object.create` as good as `new` (in contrast to SpiderMonkey). Or at least did historically. See also [this blog post for details](http://mrale.ph/blog/2014/07/30/constructor-vs-objectcreate.html).

However, there is a second reason for this being a lot slower: your two codes have different results. You would have to use

```
SudokuPuzzle.prototype.clone = function() {
   var puzzle = Object.create(SudokuPuzzle.prototype); // a new instance, without `new`
   puzzle.grid = this.grid.slice(0); // copy array (usually initialised in constructor)
   return puzzle;                    // return newly minted puzzle
};
```

to create clones that are equivalent to those created using `new SudokuPuzzle()`.

The problem is that when you use `Object.create(this)`, you are creating a new object that has a different prototype - namely, the `this` instance. Cloning very often from each other, you are creating a very complex inheritance hierarchy. And all these objects, with different prototypes, will have different hidden classes - which [**prevents optimisations**](http://mrale.ph/blog/2015/01/11/whats-up-with-monomorphism.html).

Comment: Excellent! That was the ticket! I had not considered the complex inheritance hierarchy. I guess I was doing it wrong -- always inherit from the same object where possible!

Answer (score 0):

You may check other posts [comparing Object.create and new](http://blog.getify.com/sanity-check-object-creation-performance/), for me it's intuition - if you use the *new* keyword, then the engine knows what it wants to create. If you use *Object.create* the engine needs to do some extra work to check, override the type, ...

As it is written in the post, if you are creating only a few object, the performance shouldn't matter (7s? really?). However - JS isn't really built for reflection. So methods *this.clone()* or *Object.create(this)* are really not effective.

Comment: I was impressed how well Node optimizes tail recursion -- its seems silly that they would't optimize `Object.create` -- its a core mechanism. Actually the backtracking algorithm is creating *hundreds of millions* of nodes (think of all the possibilities of filling in a Sudoku Puzzle in row-major order). The time difference is well over a full order of magnitude -- that is not a large difference!