# Javascript how can base class access derived class member?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

There is a function **hi** in the base class. There is a property **name** in the sub class.

```
function Base() {}
Base.prototype.hi = function () {
    console.log("hi " + this.name);
}

function Sub(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
Sub.prototype = new Base();

mySub = new Sub("rohita");
mySub.hi();
```

The output is

```
hi rohita
```

How is **this** from base class able to access **name** property from sub class in the **hi** function?

Does this not go against oops fundamentals?

Comment: JavaScript is not a pure OOP language.

Comment: `Sub.prototype = new Base();` is also not how its done. `Object.create( Base.prototype )` to extend correctly. If you do that, however, this should easily work.

Comment: this is giving the same output as the one given in the question. According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/17952160/3304576, the difference is calling of the constructor. That should not have an effect on my function right?

Comment: @Kiran Yeah sure, but do it right. Mostly because this seems like it might be more confusing, since javascript _is not_ OOP. It allows for those patterns, but is not made for it directly.

Comment: @DigiFriend: Kiran is having a very severe misunderstanding of OOP. This example would work exactly the same in Java, C++, C# and Go. Methods inherited from parent class are "inherited" and thus have access to the `this` of the current class. They are not called upon the base class but by the child class. Indeed, even saying that methods are called by a class is an extreme misunderstanding of OOP. Methods are called by objects, not classes.

Comment: @slebetman Given that `Base` does not have a `name` member (that could be overwritten by subclasses) at all, I doubt this would work in the languages you mentioned.

Comment: @slebetman that's cleared a lot of things. Thank you! I found this which describes exactly what you said https://youtu.be/PMfcsYzj-9M at 7:00

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding the example you're representing. All instances of `Sub` class get the `name` property, on the contrary no `Base` class instance gets access to the `name` property.

Have a careful look:

```
mySub = new Sub("rohita");
mySub.hi();
// since Sub class doesn't override the hi method, it falls back to the parent's one,
// thus this.name is valid for any instances of Sub class.. not of Base class,
// Base class instances doesn't really access the name property of Sub class..
// to prove this let's log out `this.name` for any instance of Base class,
// it'll be simply `undefined`, but for the Sub class, it's the one already defined by Sub class itself

myBase = new Base();
myBase.hi(); // => hello undefined // makes sense now, right?
```

> How is this from base class able to access name property from sub
> class in the hi function?

`this` from `Base` class doesn't really access the property of `Sub` class, `this.name` is clearly `undefined` from `Base` class in other word, any instance of `Base` class.

Since `Sub` class doesn't override the `hi` method inherited from `Base` class, invoking `hi` on `Sub` instance falls back to the parent one, in that context `this` clearly refers the `Sub` class, hence the `name` property of it.