# JS function which can be called by new Keyword only

Tags: javascript, object

Can we create a function in javascript which can be called only by new keyword? Somebody ask me how to introduce such restriction in javascript and what are the usages.

Will appreciate if somebody can answer on usage of this restriction as well.

Comment: A little research goes a long way, so please, use stack overflow to ask for help, but in all honestly, it feels like you're being a little bit lazy here. It's really not that hard to Google things.

Comment: [`new.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target).

Answer (score 3):

The `new.target` property lets you detect whether a function or constructor was called using the `new` operator:

```
function Foo() {
  if (!new.target) throw 'Foo() must be called with new';
}

try {
  Foo();
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e);
  // expected output: "Foo() must be called with new"
}
```

This may be helpful in next cases:

1. When call function `Foo()` it is implicit that new object instance will be created, but with `new` keyword - it is explicit. As result code is better to read/use/maintain/etc.
2. When you need to perform some specific stuff during creation new object instance (only once and only during creation).
3. When you need to perform all [5 steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45359916/3612353) which `new` keyword performs under the hood, and which simple function call won't perform.

Comment: This answer would be better with more explanation of what `new.target` is and how it works...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Done!)

Comment: thanks for answer but if what are the usages of this restriction on function

Comment: @jiten Done!)))

Answer (score 1):

[ES6 classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) are in fact `special functions`.

Classes require the use of the new operator to create a new instance, as such invoking a class without the new operator results in an error, as it's required for the class constructor to create a new instance.