# Instantiating JavaScript object inside React component

Tags: javascript

I have javascript class, that contains some data, and two functions.

```
export class BookStore {
  constructor() {
    this._books = [
      { id: 1,title: "How to Learn JavaScript - Vol 1", info: "Study hard"},
      { id: 2,title: "How to Learn ES6", info: "Complete all exercises :-)"},
      { id: 3,title: "How to Learn React",info: "Complete all your CA's"},
      { id: 4,title: "Learn React", info: "Don't drink beers, until Friday (after four)"
    }]
    this._nextID= 5;
  }

  get books(){ return this._books;}

  addBook(book){
    book.id = this._nextID;
    this._books.push(book);
    this._nextID++;
  }
}
```

Now I want to make an object of the class, and console log Its book items

```
const book =Object.create(BookStore)
console.log(book.books)
```

I have tried several things, like the Object creates method, and trying calling it directly.

```
import {BookStore} from './BookStore/BookStore.js'
```

Comment: What does this have to do with React? There's no React code in your question.

Comment: `Object.create` should receive an object (can be an instance of a class) not a class. From JS point you may try `const book = new Bookstore` but I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. Please also clarify where do you run the code? Do you import the file in node?

Comment: Have you tried `new BookStore` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `Object.create` instead of `new` keyword for instantiating the class.

Use the following code :

```
const book = new BookStore();
console.log(book.books);
```

`Object.create` just copies the prototype of the objects, but doesn't call the `constructor`.

You can read more about [Understanding Object.create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166616/understanding-the-difference-between-object-create-and-new-somefunction) in the related question.