# Difference between Object.create & new keyword in javaScript

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance, proto

why output is coming on one case and not on the other? both of them have a variable inside their **proto** , yet I am getting undefined in one case.

[image]

Comment: Please post code as text, not as picture.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding the difference between Object.create() and new SomeFunction()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166616/understanding-the-difference-between-object-create-and-new-somefunction)

Answer (score 0):

When you type `p.constructor.prototype.a` the JavaScript checks for property `constructor` in the object itself but it does not have it. When that occurs, it goes over the prototype chain via `__proto__`. The problem here is that the object `p` and it's prototype(s) does not have property `constructor`. This is caused by use of `Object.create()`. Difference between it and `new` is already described in [Understanding the difference between Object.create() and new SomeFunction()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166616/understanding-the-difference-between-object-create-and-new-somefunction) as @adiga commented under you post :)

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple.

new a is Object.create(a.prototype)

while Object.create(a) is different than Object.create(a.prototype).
new runs constructor code while object does not run constructor.

See following example:

```
function a(){
    this.b = 'xyz';
};

a.prototype.c = 'test';
var x = new a();
var y = Object.create(a);

//Using New Keyword
console.log(x); //Output is object
console.log(x.b); //Output is xyz.
console.log(x.c); //Output is test.

//Using Object.create()
console.log(y); //Output is function
console.log(y.b); //Output is undefined
console.log(y.c); //Output is undefined
```