# Import module inside the loop is a bad practice?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a javascript module and I import it at the beginning of my main / main code and in it I execute a forEach, in this main code there is a loop that calls the methods of the module:

```
results.forEach(function(result) {
     for(const item of items .......){
        exampleModule.metodo(result, item)
     }
});
```

So far so good, the problem is that the values of the module are being mixed, the module is not dynamic according to the item Y of the result X, it kind of "disturbs" everything ...

I thought of a way to solve it, I do not know if it is the best practice, declare const exampleModule = require ('./modules/example.js') within an object and give that object a reference, such as item ID , since each ID will be unique:

```
let objetos = {}
results.forEach(function(result) {
     for(const item of items .......){
        objetos[item.id] = require('./modules/example.js')
        objetos[item.id].metodo(result, item)
     }
});
```

In short, I want each loop item to create an instance of the module without it being interfered with, if I instantiate the module in the item of position 0, everything in the module should only be used by that item 0, if it is item 1 the same thing, 1 n can change values of the module that is being used by position 0 and so on, is it possible? Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js caches the modules which are imported. So there's no side effect of requiring them in a loop. The caching is explained [here in docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching).

And yes, it's not best practice to import modules deep in the code as it's considered less readable. You can always do something like:

```
let objetos = {}
const exampleModule = require('./modules/example.js');
results.forEach(function(result) {
     for(const item of items .......){
        objetos[item.id] = Object.assign({}, exampleModule);
        objetos[item.id].metodo(result, item)
     }
});
```

Comment: How cool, it copies all the properties of the module! I did not know I had this function, does that solve the issue of mixing the values in the module?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same idea, and checked it once, but it's basically a singleton what is returned by the require() function.

if you have

```
jQuery = require('jquery');
jQuery.fn.foobar = function() {
   this.css({color:red});
}
```

and then in another file you can do

```
$ = require('jquery');
$('hello').foobar();
```

The only condition is that the string you use to `require()` is the same case.

```
require('libs/myModule.js') != require('libs/mymodule.js');
```

behind the scenes a map is created:

```
 objects = {
    'jquery' : ....
    'add' : ....
    'strcasecomp' : ....
    '/www/htdocs/site/libs/myModule.js' : ...
 }
```

what happens when you `require()` is that if the object exists in the map, it's returned. If it doesn't exist, the relevant file is found, instantiated, mapped and returned.

Comment: Oh I understood, thank you very much for your answer but I think the answer from above where we call the assign method can solve my problem.

Comment: @viniciussvl You had probably a singleton problem, where all the objects in your array were the same instance. When you modified one item, it was modified in all. I just wanted to illuminate the underlying mechanics for you :-) I find it mostly useful to know "how" something works, so you can better work with it.

Comment: Yes I understood it perfectly, if it changes in one changes at all, I was just wondering how to solve this.

Comment: @viniciussvl the `Object.assign()` works to copy an objects properties, instantiating also works  `new Foobar()` if they are instantiateable classes or functions. it all depends on the implementation of the library. Always check what is expected. You might sometimes need [Object.create()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) or [new Object()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166616/understanding-the-difference-between-object-create-and-new-somefunction#17952160)