# Why the 'new' keyword doesn't change the displayed constructor in the console

Tags: javascript

When not using the 'new' keyword, the constructor logged in the console shows what the constructor of the object is and it also changes when I change the `__proto__` of the object it the console also displays what the current constructor of the object is. But when using the 'new' keyword even I change the `__proto__` the console still shows the constructor of the original constructor that made the object.

Without 'new' keyword photo
[image: Without 'new' keyword photo]

With 'new' keyword photo

[image: With 'new' keyword photo]

The console displays what is the current constructor of the object is, and it changes when I change its `__proto__`

```
function Human(){}
function Animal(){}
const obj = Object.create(Human.prototype)
console.log(obj)
Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, Animal.prototype)
console.log(obj)
```

But when using the new keyword even if change the `__proto__` of the object it still displays the original constructor it was created from.

```
function Human(){}
function Animal(){}
const obj = new Human()
console.log(obj)
Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, Animal.prototype)
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: I think this will answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166616/understanding-the-difference-between-object-create-and-new-somefunction

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding the difference between Object.create() and new SomeFunction()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166616/understanding-the-difference-between-object-create-and-new-somefunction)

Comment: can you post Human and Animal class definitions?

Comment: you may also want to take a look at this article on how prototypes and inheritance work in javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain