# Why is it not printing undefined?

Tags: javascript

```
const person = {
  isHuman: false,
  name:"Jon",
  printIntroduction: function() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
};

const me = Object.create(person);

me.name = 'Matthew'; 
me.isHuman = true; 
delete me.name
me.printIntroduction();
```

output :  "Jon"

When I'm deleting the name property of "me" object, why is it pointing to person object's name property?

please suggest good reference material to understand this.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166616/understanding-the-difference-between-object-create-and-new-somefunction, maybe it helps

Answer (score 3):

Because "person" is the "me"-object's prototype. If a property is not found on an object (because of deletion), JS is looking up the prototype-chain for that property. That's why you're getting "Jon".

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Comment: Exactly. This link explains how the `delete` method works through the prototype chain: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#description

Answer (score 1):

[`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) creates a new object using an existing object as the prototype of the new object it creates.

The properties of the prototype are not copied into the new object created by `Object.create()`. The prototype inheritance works by linking the new object to its prototype object.

When it is created, `me` does not have any property on its own. It inherits the properties of `person` and this is visible if you run `me.printIntroduction()` immediately after `const me = Object.create(person);`.

When a property (attribute or function) of the new object is read (e.g. `console.log(me.name)`), the interpreter looks for the property (`name`) in the object (`me`). If such a property does not exist then it searches for it in the prototype (which is the `person` object in this case). Searching for the property in the prototype object works the same; if it cannot be found there, then it is looked up in the prototype of the prototype object and so on until it reaches the root of the prototype chain.

When a property is set in the object then the prototype chain is not walked any more. It is set directly in the object used in the statement. The same happens when a property is deleted.

Use [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) to find the list of property names that are own to `me` and not inherited from `person`:

```js
const person = {
  isHuman: false,
  name:"Jon",
  printIntroduction: function() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
};

const me = Object.create(person);
me.printIntroduction();
console.log({ own_properties_after_creation: Object.getOwnPropertyNames(me)});

me.name = 'Matthew'; 
me.isHuman = true; 
me.printIntroduction();
console.log({ own_properties_after_set: Object.getOwnPropertyNames(me)});

delete me.name
me.printIntroduction();
console.log({ own_properties_after_delete: Object.getOwnPropertyNames(me)});
```

Read more about the [prototype inheritance in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) in the [JavaScript documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript).