# Usage of Object.create vs new

Tags: javascript

Are the following two constructions identical, or are there any differences between them?

```
let x = new Item(v1, v2, ...)
```

And:

```
let x = Object.create(Item.prototype)
x.constructor(v1, v2, ...)
```

The code I was writing to see which one to use is the following (though for academic purposes):

```js
'use strict';
function Meal(type) {
    this.type = type;
};
Meal.isMeal = function(obj) {console.log(obj instanceof Meal)};
Meal.prototype.eat = function() {console.log(`${this.type} has been eaten!`)};

// let breakfast = new Meal('Breakfast');
let breakfast = Object.create(Meal.prototype);
breakfast.constructor('Breakfast')

Meal.isMeal(breakfast);
breakfast.eat();
```

Comment: They're obviously not *identical*. But in your `Meal` case, they can both serve the same purpose.

Comment: "*to see which one to use*" - to create a new `Meal` instance, just use `new`. Why make it complicated? If you can't see a difference or advantage, go for the idiomatic solution.

Comment: @Bergi I see thanks for those links. It seems like they serve the same purpose, so that answers my question, thanks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17952160/651174