# question about prototypes and inheritance with 'new' and 'object.create'

Tags: javascript, object

I'm learning about objects, prototypes and inheritances. I got a doubt regarding the following code, from a conceptual viewpoint:

```
function Animal() {
  this.eat = function() {
    console.log("nom nom nom"); 
  }
};

const dog = new Animal();
const cat = Object.create(Animal);

dog.eat();                    // nom nom nom
cat.eat();                    // cat.eat is not a function
```

This doesn't work either:

```
const cat = Object.create(Animal.prototype);

cat.eat();                    // cat.eat is not a function
```

The only way to make it work on `cat` is to assign the function to Animal.prototype.eat on a separate line.

As I read on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166616/understanding-the-difference-between-object-create-and-new-somefunction?noredirect=1&lq=1), `new Animal` is essentially  `Object.create(Animal.prototype)`. So, why is `dog` inheriting the `eat` function (which, I understand, is an 'Own Property' of the Animal constructor) and cat isn't, even when created with `Animal.prototype` as its parameter?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Because it's 2022, you might want to look into using `class` declarations.

Answer (score 0):

Your Animal() constructor assigns the function to **each distinct instance**, not to the prototype. The function is not on the prototype object, so Object.create() will not provide access to the `.eat()` method.