# Don't understand JavaScript prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm reading JavaScript Good Parts. There is an example:

```
if (typeof Object.create !== 'function') {
    Object.create = function(o) {
        var F = function(){};
        F.prototype = o;
        return new F();
    }
}
```

Can somebody explain to me what this means? To begin with, Object already has a method with this name because when I run this:

```
console.log(typeof Object.create);
```

The output is 'function'?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding Crockford's Object.create shim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141086/understanding-crockfords-object-create-shim)

Comment: I think [this link](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/understanding-javascript-prototypes/) explains it better.

Comment: `Object.create` was added in ES5, the latest js standard. JavaScript: The Good Parts was written before that. That's why `typeof Object.create` is `function`.

Comment: @Zirak Gotcha. Another question. What is this method definition trying to achieve. Sorry for my ignorance. I read the links that people gave me but I still don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your "To begin with...", you might still run into Javascript environments where

```
console.log(typeof Object.create);
```

will report

```
undefined
```

or some such (assuming you even have a console object with a log function available.)  The reason for that outer `if (typeof Object.create !== 'function')` wrapper is to only define this in the case that your JS environment doesn't already do so.  There are many older browsers and other environments where your code might one day run that could conceivably not have `Object.create` defined.

Now as to how this actual function works, its based on how JS handles objects.  Objects are simply collections of named properties, or more properly associations between String names and property values.  But many also have a special property, which is their `prototype`.  This is simply a pointer to another object.  That object can also have its own `prototype` object, and so on.  Eventually, though, the prototype chain dies out when the `prototype` of one of these objects is null.  These prototype objects also are collections of named properties, and when the Javascript engine is searching your object for a named property, if it doesn't find it directly on your object, it checks to see if your object's prototype might contain it, and if not, if the prototype of that object might contain it, and so on, until the chain dies out.

The point of these prototype objects is that they can be shared.  Several objects, or even several million objects, can share a single prototype.  This is substantially different from how class-based inheritance schemes work, but it can often be put to a similar purpose.  You can define a single copy of a function, and all objects created from a common constructor function will use that one copy.  Before such techniques as `Object.create` were created, this was the only real means of doing Object-oriented programming in Javascript.

Crockford's code is using that older technique to simulate part of what the newer technique is supposed to do.  `Object.create` defines some behaviors that can't really be achieved through the older mechanisms, but the most basic behaviors are simply to create a new object whose prototype is the specified object.  That's exactly what the older technique, using `F.prototype = o; return new F();` accomplished.  So this code is pretty much the standard way to shim the new behavior into older environments.  For another example of this, see the [MDN create page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create/)

Comment: What is this method trying to achieve? Can you bring an example of where it would be useful?

Comment: That's what I was _trying_ to do with the long post above.  :-(  The code is trying to give you a mostly working version of `Object.create` in environments that don't have one.  And `Object.create` is a simpler way of creating an object with a specified prototype object.