# What's the advantage of goog.inherits' use of a temporary constructor?

Tags: javascript, google-closure

From Google's Closure library:

```
goog.inherits = function(childCtor, parentCtor) {
  /** @constructor */
  function tempCtor() {};
  tempCtor.prototype = parentCtor.prototype;
  childCtor.superClass_ = parentCtor.prototype;
  childCtor.prototype = new tempCtor();
  /** @override */
  childCtor.prototype.constructor = childCtor;
};
```

What is the advantage to the temporary constructor that is created?

Is there a reason the code doesn't just look like this:

```
goog.inherits = function(childCtor, parentCtor) {
  /** @constructor */
  childCtor.superClass_ = parentCtor.prototype;
  childCtor.prototype = new parentCtor();
  /** @override */
  childCtor.prototype.constructor = childCtor;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first snippet is not calling the `parentCtor` - it is not instantiating an object with invoking the constructor on it, it just inherits from the `parentCtor.prototype` - actually it's a workaround for [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) (very old browsers lack support of it). See also [Understanding Crockford's Object.create shim](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10141086/1048572) on how the `tempCtor` works and [What is the reason *[not]* to use the 'new' keyword here?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12592913/1048572) on the undesirability of calling the parent.

Comment: Oh okay - so would `function (childCtor, parentCtor) { childCtor.prototype = Object.create(parentCtor); }` do the trick?

Comment: `Object.create(parentCtor.prototype)`, but yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use "new parentCtor" if:
(a) it will succeed without any parameters
(b) you want the values set on the "this" value in parentCtor on your prototype.

You see people do this in simple cases:

```
var C = function() {};
C.prototype = new P();
```

But you can see how this can fail if P is:

```
var P = function(a) {a.x()}  // throws if "a" is undefined.
```

The tempCtor avoids this.