# create an object that extends another

Tags: javascript

I have an object like this:

```
var source = (function(undefined) {
    var o;
    function s(o) {
        if(!o || typeof o === 'object') {
            o = o || {};
            o.a = typeof o.a === 'string' ? o.a : 'A';
            o.b = typeof o.b === 'string' ? o.b : 'B';
            this.o = o;
        }
    }
    s.prototype.v = function() {
        // some function
    };
    s.prototype.x = function() {
        // some function
    };
    return s;
})();
```

I want to use another similar to extend the first.

```
var extender = (function(undefined) {
    var o;
    function e(o) {
        if(!o || typeof o === 'object') {
            o = o || {};
            o.c = typeof o.c === 'number' ? o.c : 3;
            o.d = typeof o.d === 'number' ? o.d : 4;
            this.o = o;
        }
    }
    e.prototype.y = function(m) {
        // some function
    };
    e.prototype.z = function(m) {
        // some function
    };
    return e;
})();
```

I can add `this.s = new source(o);` to the function and with some small changes to my second object can tie everything into the first but I was thinking there might be a better way.

Comment: Why on earth would you call your variable `undefined`? That's one of the most evil things you can do in Javascript.

Comment: @Antimony: No; he's creating a local `undefined` variable in case someone else sets `window.undefined`.  jQuery does this.

Comment: Why would that be a problem? And wtf why should somebody set window.undefined?

Comment: No idea why someone would do it. But it is a good practice to avoid problems. The code I posted here is just a sample. The real code has some validations that require undefined to be UNDEFINED.

Comment: @SLaks Oh, that's a neat trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine the snippets from the other two answers to the correct solution, you probably want

```
var extender = (function(undefined) {
    // var o; - That's useless, `o` is a parameter of the constructor
    function e(o) {
        source.call(this, o); // invoke the `source` constructor on this instance
        o = this.o; // and get the created `o` object
        // …to extend it:
        o.c = typeof o.c === 'number' ? o.c : 3;
        o.d = typeof o.d === 'number' ? o.d : 4;
    }

    // make the prototype a new object inheriting `v` and `x`:
    e.prototype = Object.create(source.prototype);
    // then extend it
    e.prototype.y = function(m) {
        …
    };
    e.prototype.z = function(m) {
        …
    };
    return e;
})();
```

See docs for [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) and [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Comment: Uh, I didn't. Gonna comment on it :-)

Comment: @tntu: No it's not. It would create a whole *instance*, and invoke the constructor - yet without any parameters (which would not be meaningful). You only want the inheritance, creating instance things (in the constructor) which are shared by all `extender` objects can create serious issues.

Comment: Then both would point to the same object and you would create `y` and `z` on `source.prototype` basically. There's nothing wrong with using the [common and old shim for `Object.create`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10141086) to make it work smoothly in older browsers

Comment: Thank you for the effort. You win :) Feel free to remove you comments to leave this question tidy.

Comment: @tntu: Why "tidy"? I know that my post was not really comprehensive, and many things not well explained. The responses on your extra questions are part of my answer, and can still help others to understand the topic (which might work better if the questions were still there :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:-

```
Object.create(o);//where o is object to inherit from
```

For cross browser:-

```
 if (typeof Object.create !== "function")
            Object.create = function(o) {
                function F() {}
                F.prototype = o;
                return new F();
 };
```

Comment: Nope. Object.create is new object function for creating a new object from the object passed to it. Modern browsers have support of this. The "if" is for the browsers not having this support.

Comment: Is there a solution for all browsers? Plus I need to tap into the source object from inside the main function of the second. I need to be able to pass the initialization parameter to the extender and from ti to the source.

Comment: The "if" is for cross browser implementation. You can send arguments to Object.create();

For more info:-
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Comment: What do I do in the `else` case?

Comment: Nothing. You don't need any else.

Comment: I got it. I think the late hour is getting to me.

Comment: It works but, here's the thing, the source is loaded in extender before the extender is instantiated thus the options passed to the extender do not get passed to the source. If you know what I mean?

Comment: I am not following you. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: As you can see the object are designed to be instanced with an object parameter that contains the configuration options. When I instantiate the extender object and pass it the configuration, it needs to check the configuration for what it is expecting, then instantiate the source object and pass the configuration to it. The result should be an object containing the prototypes of both with a single o variable containing both configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following two lines:

`e.prototype = source.prototype;`

`source.call(this, o);`

They are the solution.

Of course I had to make some adjustments to the config in order to ensure both operate.

```
var source = (function(undefined) {
    function s(o) {
        // config
        this.o = {};
        if(!o || typeof o === 'object') {
            o = o || {};
            this.o.a = typeof o.a === 'string' ? o.a : 'A';
            this.o.b = typeof o.b === 'string' ? o.b : 'B';
        }
    }
    s.prototype.x = function(m) {
        console.log(m);
    };
    return s;
})();
var extender = (function(undefined) {
    function e(o) {
        // instanciate parent
        source.call(this, o);
        // child config
        if(!o || typeof o === 'object') {
            o = o || {};
            e = this.o;
            e.c = typeof o.c === 'number' ? o.c : 1;
            e.d = typeof o.d === 'number' ? o.d : 2;
        }
    }
    // inherit
    e.prototype = source.prototype;
    // extend
    e.prototype.y = function(m) {
        console.log(m);
    };
    return e;
})();
var e = new extender({d:3});
console.log(e);
```

Comment: I don't think `source.call(o)` is a solution. Did you notice it creates the `o` property (with the `a` and `b` subproperties) on the `o` parameter which you passed, instead of the result object (`this` inside the `e` constructor)?

Comment: Also notice that you [should not use `new`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12592913/1048572) for the prototype object creation. In your case you might even get [issues with nested objects](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10131052)

Comment: Try to log `source.prototype.y` and be surprised :-)

Comment: You want `y` to be only on `extender.prototype`, but `v` and `x` on both? If you assign them to each other, there will be only one object - and all properties be everywhere.

Comment: That is what I want. It is not a problem. Thank you for explaining. Now I know the difference between yours and mine. You could say yours inherits and mine extends.