# function F() { if (!(this instanceof F)) { return new F() }; ... }

Tags: javascript

What is the usage of the construct: `function F() { if (!(this instanceof F)) { return new F() }; ... }`?

I found this in a `pty.js` for Node. Here is the original code:

```
function Terminal(file, args, opt) {
  if (!(this instanceof Terminal)) {
     return new Terminal(file, args, opt);
  }

  var self = this
     , env
     , cwd
     , name
     , cols
     , rows
     , term;
-------------------SKIP-----------------------------------
  Terminal.total++;
  this.socket.on('close', function() {
     Terminal.total--;
     self._close();
     self.emit('exit', null);
  });

  env = null;
}
```

Comment: This effectively forces the function to be called like `new Terminal(...)`...because if it's not (`if (!(this instanceof Terminal))`), then it forces it (`return new Terminal(file, args, opt);`)

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should I automatically create an object even if \`new\` is forgotten?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20859985/when-should-i-automatically-create-an-object-even-if-new-is-forgotten)

Comment: Related, but not a duplicate.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It means that if the function was called without the `new` operator, it will automagically return a new instance.

For example, if you didn't have this safeguard, and did this...

```
var t = Terminal();
```

...then the `this` while executing `Terminal()` would point to `window` (or your global object, fancy non-browser guy/gal), definitely *not* what you want.

By determining that `this` is in fact an instance of `Terminal`, then we can proceed. Otherwise, the safeguard returns a new object.

Then we can simply use both forms...

```
var t = Terminal(); // Will be same as `new Terminal()`
```

Comment: +1 irrespective of your inclusion of the word "automagically". ;-D

Comment: Is the use of this construct considered "bad programming", or would this safeguard + allowing this usage be fine?

Comment: @BrendanAshworth I wouldn't say so. jQuery does the same thing with `$.Deferred()`, and point out in the docs that it's okay to do so, for whatever that's worth.

Answer (score 12):

It's just to make sure it will work even if `F` is called without `new`.

When you call `F` with `new`, in that function `this` is the new instance.

Then, if `this` is not an instance of `F` (`!(this instanceof F)`), then that means that `F` was not called using `new`. In this case, `F` calls itself, now with `new`.

Answer (score 9):

Further to the great explanations in this thread, it is interesting to see what happens under the hood. The ECMAScript specification (where Javascript is based) [defines](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1) a **global** object. This is implemented differently in different execution environments. In your typical browser, it is the `window` object while in Node.js it is the `root` object. Every function defined "in the wild" (not attached to a user created object) will become a property of the global object. In Node.js you can try:

```
> function Test() {};
> root.Test
[Function: Test]
```

Now, the `this` variable points to **the object that the function is a member of**. So in the example above:

```
> function Test() { 
... console.log(this === root); 
... };
> Test()
true
```

Same goes for your function `Terminal`. If you run it, `this` will point to the **global** object which is of course **not** an instance of `Terminal`!

When calling a function using the `new` operator, an object is returned which will have access to a property called `constructor` that will point back to that function. It is something equivalent to:

```
> var instance = {};
> instance.constructor = Terminal;
> instance.constructor();
```

So, when the conditional fails and the Terminal function is run through the `new Terminal()` line, `this` will point to a newly created instance which **is** of type Terminal!

If you want to get more technical, `instance` does not have a `constructor` property itself. It is instead linked (via the prototype chain*), to a private object** (created by the runtime) that has a `constructor` property pointing to the Terminal function. That private object is pointed **back to** by the function through a `prototype` property. [D.Crockford](https://7chan.org/pr/src/OReilly_JavaScript_The_Good_Parts_May_2008.pdf) presents this in *pseudocode* as follows:

```
Terminal.prototype = {constructor: Terminal};
```

Again, this is **only** when you call the function with `new`.

** If a property is not found, the object will look it up at the object pointed to by the `__proto__` property.*

*** (imagine something like an object called `_Terminal` that you cannot access by name)*