# What is the significance of this JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript

What I think this is doing is looking to see if this object has already been instantiated and exists within the scope?  Why do we need to use a triple equal sign to determine?

```
   function viewmodel(parent) {

            if (false === (this instanceof viewmodel)) {
                return new viewmodel(parent);
            }

    };
```

Comment: That's only a pedantic way to say `if (!(this instanceof viewmodel))`.

Comment: More information: [When should I automatically create an object even if `new` is forgotten?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20859985/1048572)

Comment: `false ===` is a horrible way to negate a boolean value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a strict equality comparison there. `instanceof` yields `true` or `false`, so this is entirely sufficient:

```
if (!(this instanceof viewmodel))
```

Answer (score 3):

The triple equals prevents implicit datatype conversion.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons) for more information.

Comment: There's no conversion between `boolean` and `!boolean`.

Comment: In this case, no.  I gave this answer for completeness sake, as the OP asked about the triple equals sign specifically.
As other answers have mentioned, it is somewhat superfluous.  In other comparisons, it could have significance, as seen in the linked question.