# How to transform a native collection object in another personal object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, collections, javascript-objects, instanceof

Like how the `jQuery` uses the `jQuery` method for return a `jQuery` object, but how a format of collection (`Array`, `NodeList`,...). I wonder how jQuery does.

That way I can convert a `NodeList` object, for example, on a personal object.

```
jQuery("li") //=> [<li>...</li>, <li>...</li>, <li>...</li>]
jQuery("li") instanteof jQuery //=> true
jQuery("li") instanteof Array //=> false
jQuery("li") instanteof NodeList //=> false
jQuery("li") instanteof HTMLCollection //=> false
```

Comment: `jQuery("body").toArray()` or `.get()` does what you want.

Comment: There is no (straightforward) way to create your own `NodeList` or `HTMLCollection`. But there's absolutely zero reason to do so either. What would you want this for?

Comment: @Bergi For Knowledge. I think you got it wrong. I do not want to convert a jQuery object to an array. I want to know how jQuery to create a collection that is not native of the JS.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "pseudo collection" or "create a collection that is not native". jQuery just creates instances like every other class as well; `function jQuery(){}; var x = new jQuery; x instanceof jQuery`. No magic here.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, you're right, but we need not explicitly instantiate the jQuery. I find it cool. Just make a call to jQuery class and pass a parameter to it, then it returns in an instance of itself, but as a collection of objects. And this collection is not instance of array.

Comment: Returning an instance even if called without `new` [is pretty simple](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20859985/1048572). That jQuery instances have integer properties and a `.length` like arrays isn't anything special either.

Comment: @Bergi Perfect. Thank so much!!! Example of the compilation [link text]http://jsfiddle.net/rplaurindo/fheg7bs0/1/"[/link]

Comment: Uh, did I mention that [you should not use this pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12143833/1048572)? Don't make `build` the actual constructor, it's confusing as hell.

Comment: @bergi how to inserting as text link here?

Comment: [Just regular markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) :-)

Comment: @Bergi thanks. What better way of dealing with the builder? Instantiate explicitly?

Comment: Either put the `if (!(this instanceof My…)) return new My…(…);` right in the regular constructor, or - if you feel having to use a factory and a separate constructor - don't put the actual constructor on the `.prototype` of the factory function.

Comment: @Bergi like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rplaurindo/fheg7bs0/3/)?

Comment: [Yes](http://jsfiddle.net/fheg7bs0/4/)