# OOP Programming with javascript: Making sure that this points to the right thing regardless of how the object is instantiated

Tags: javascript, oop

from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

> Making sure that this points to the right thing regardless of how the
>   object is instantiated can be difficult. However, there is a simple
>   idiom to make this easier.

```
var Person = function(firstName) {
  if (this instanceof Person) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
  } else {
    return new Person(firstName);
  }
}
```

Why are we returning new Person?

How can the else case actually occur?

Comment: near duplicate of [When should I automatically create an object even if `new` is forgotten?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20859985/1048572)

Answer (score 2):

The `Person` is just a regular function. The difference makes how it is invoked:

**1) It can be invoked as a constructor**

```
 var p = new Person('Bill Gates');
```

The `this` context in the constructor is an instance of the `Person`. `this instanceof Person` evaluates to `true`.
The newly created object is automatically returned when invoking the function as a constructor.

**2) Invoked as a regular function**

```
var p = Person('Bill Gates');
```

`this` is the `Window` object or `undefined` in strict mode. `this instanceof Person` evaluates to `false`.
However to still receive an object on simple invocation, `new Person(firstName)` is called manually to return the correct object.

Check more details in [this post](http://rainsoft.io/gentle-explanation-of-this-in-javascript/).

Comment: further down on the linked page you will find: "// Define the Student constructor". Now we could call `Student("Bill Gates", "Coding")` without the `new`... wouldn't that return us a person instead of a student?

Comment: @Toskan Without new `Student("Bill Gates", "Coding")` will just return `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement that your "class" function `Person` gets called with the `new` operator.

If it does, the value of `this` inside the function will be an instance of the `Person` class.

If it doesn't, as in `var p = Person('Toskan')`, then the value of `this` will be the global object, and the prototype won't be set correctly to the `Person.prototype` object. To get around that, the function explicitly returns the result of calling the function with the `new` keyword.