# Modifying Array.prototype causes errors in other js library

Tags: javascript, asp.net, crystal-reports

I'm using [Crystal Reports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa686983%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in ASP.NET webforms to show some report files. The framework generates some javascript that which is used for the UI logic.

Un-minified version (using a beautifier): http://pastebin.com/uryjRZF7

The thing that bothers me is that as soon as I do *any* modification to the array prototype, the script above throws 2 errors. It looks like this in firebug (yes, I know, but I can't un-minify it at this point):

> TypeError: E[D].getHTML is not a function
>
> ...conWidget("iconMenu_icon_"+C,B,IconMenuWidget_iconClickCB,K,F,J,G,P,L,A,N,false)...
>
> TypeError: A.layer is null
>
> ...conWidget("iconMenu_icon_"+C,B,IconMenuWidget_iconClickCB,K,F,J,G,P,L,A,N,false)...

For example, this would make the errors appear:

```
if(!Array.prototype.somethingVeryUnique) {

    Array.prototype.somethingVeryUnique = function () {

        return this.length;
    };
}
```

How can this possibly interfer with the auto generated file?!

Update:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "somethingUnique", {
    enumerable: false,
    writable: true,
    value: function () {

    }
});
```

If I make it non-enumerable, it works. However, `object.defineProperty` doesn't work in IE7, which I need to support.

Is there any way to make a non-enumerable property without it?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy What do you mean by non-filtered?

Comment: See @HMR's answer, that's what I meant. Since you changed your question, it now seems to be a dupe of [Object.defineProperty in ES5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830800/object-defineproperty-in-es5) :(

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Well, a part of it is. But I wouldn't call this a dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are probably using `for(something in array)` and the prototype added member will show up if you don't check `array.hasOwnProperty(something);` Best is to [not extend native JS objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Bad_practice.3A_Extension_of_native_prototypes).

Comment: Well, extending native types comes down to personal preferences. Extending `Object` *is* bad. However, `String`, `Array` etc can be useful in my optinion. But I suppose you're right about the looping. Thanks