# strange javascript property definition using polymer

Tags: javascript, properties, polymer, web-component

In the following code `xFoo` will be an object that (or its prototype) has an actual property `bar` with a value of 5 and it will will have an actual method `foo()`. What kind of object notation is this? This is not how I define properties in ECMAScript 5. I would have expected that `xFoo.bar` is an object that has a function `get()` and that `xFoo.foo` is an object that has a method `value()`. What am I missing here?

```
var XFoo = document.registerElement('x-foo', {
    prototype: Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype, {
        bar: {
            get: function () {
                return 5;
            }
        },
        foo: {
            value: function () {
                alert('foo() called');
            }
        }
    })
});

var xFoo = new XFoo();
```

Comment: Looks like syntax is close to `Object.defineProperty`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Object.defineProperty in ES5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830800/object-defineproperty-in-es5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, my guess was correct:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Parameters

Sorry, but have you at least tried to google `javascript Object.create`?

Comment: Ooops, dumb question, I wish I could delete it. Thank's for pointing out the obvious! *blush*

Answer (score 0):

> What kind of object notation is this? This is not how I define properties in ECMAScript 5.

Of course it is. Just have a look at the [docs of ES 5 `Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create). It uses the same [***property descriptors***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description) as [`Object.defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) does.