# TypeError : React object is undefined on createElement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabs, material-ui, appbar

I am new to `React` and `Material UI` and I am attempting to create an `AppBar` with `Tabs` as children. My current implementation looks like this:

```
import {React, PropTypes, Component} from 'react';
import TodoTextInput from './TodoTextInput';
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
import baseTheme from 'material-ui/styles/baseThemes/lightBaseTheme'
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme'
import {Tabs, Tab} from 'material-ui/Tabs';
import {AppBar} from 'material-ui/AppBar';

const styles = {
  headline: {
    fontSize: 24,
    paddingTop: 16,
    marginBottom: 12,
    fontWeight: 400
  }
};

function handleActive(tab) {
  alert(`A tab with this route property ${tab.props['data-route']} was activated.`);
}
const defaultStyle = {
  marginLeft: 20
};

class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <header className="header">
      <AppBar title="TEST" />
        <Tabs>
          <Tab label="Tab 1" >
            <div>

            </div>
          </Tab>
          <Tab label="Tab 2" >
            <div>

            </div>
          </Tab>
          <Tab label="Tab 3" >
            <div>

            </div>
          </Tab>
          <Tab label="Tab 4" >
            <div>

            </div>
          </Tab>
        </Tabs>
        {children}
      </header>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = Header;
```

I'm getting an error that states:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_react.React.createElement')
```

I am unsure on how to fix this problem. Please help!

Answer (score 31):

You are importing React wrong, you're close though. Change it to

`import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';`

Think of React as the parent and the others as children. You could also just import React and access the other with `React.PropTypes` and `React.Component`.

Comment: For the difference between (the incorrect) ```import { React } from 'react';``` and the correct ```import React from 'react';```, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795819/when-should-i-use-curly-braces-for-es6-import

Answer (score 3):

I was getting error: "**React.createElement is not a function**" and for my situation the fix was to change this:

`import React from "react-native";`

To

`import React from "react";`

Thanks, I fixed this by changing **import React from 'react-native'** to **import React from 'react'**.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing same issue. This solves it:

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'; //Right 
import {React,useState} from 'react-native'; //Wrong
```