# What is use of curly braces in an ES6 import statement?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I can see there are two different ways to import:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
```

The second one has brackets. What is the difference between the two? And when should I add brackets?

Comment: Suggested reading http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html no need to ask this on SO

Comment: Brief answer: this is es6 destructuring coming into play. `var React` will be assigned to everything exported from `'react'`, and `var render` will be assigned to the `render` property of whatever is exported from `'react-dom'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I use curly braces for ES6 import?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795819/when-should-i-use-curly-braces-for-es6-import)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Well, the difference between whether you should import your components *within brackets or without it* lies in the way you `export` it.

There are two types of exports

1. Default Export
2. Named Export

A component can have **one default export and zero or more named** exports.

If a component is a default export then you need to import it without brackets.

E.g.,

```
export default App;
```

The import it as

```
import App from './path/to/App';
```

A named export could be like

```
export const A = 25;
```

or

```
export {MyComponent};
```

Then you can import it as

```
import {A} from './path/to/A';
```

or

```
import {A as SomeName} from './path/to/A';
```

If your component has one default export and few named exports, you can even mix them together while importing

```
import App, {A as SomeName} from './path/to/file';
```

Similarly in case of `react` and `react-dom`, `React` and `ReactDOM` are `default exports` respectively whereas, for instance `Component` is a `named export` in `react` and `render` is a named export in `react-dom`. That's the reason you can either do

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

and then use

```
ReactDOM.render()
```

or use it like mentioned in your question.

Comment: this answer seems very definitive... **one** default export **plus** multiple named exports (allowed per script file)... and then to import default export: no braces, import named export: has to use braces. Is one of the official reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export ? (part of the ES6 standard)

Comment: But why is it made this distinction between default and named :)?

Answer (score 7):

First of all, a big thank you to all the other answers.

Here is a summary of all the above, in one answer.

**Context with examples**

```
import React from 'react';          // Importing without braces
import { render } from 'react-dom'; // Importing with braces
```

To be able to understand `import`, it's important to firstly understand `export` and its types.

**Types of exports**

There are mainly two types of exports, 'default' and 'named'. Whether to use braces or not, depends entirely on which type of exported variable is being imported.

So, the short answer is that variables exported as default, do *not* need braces, but named variables *do need* to be imported with braces.

Now, let's look at some practical examples of how to import and export both types.

**Default: How to export and import**

- exporting

```
// Module1.js
export default App;

// Module2.js
export default myVariable;

// Module3.js
export default myFunction;

// Please note that there can only be one default export per module!
```

- importing

```
import App from './Module1'
import AppRenamed from './Module1'

import myVariable from, './Module2'
import myFunction from './Module3'

// Please note that default modules can be renamed when importing
// ... and they will still work!
```

**Named: How to export and import**

- exporting

```
export const A = 42
export const myA = 43
export const Something = 44

export { cube, foo, graph };

// Note how there can be several named exports per module
// exported in groups or individually
```

- importing

```
import { A, myA } from './my-module.js';
import { Something as aRenamedVar } from './my-module.js';
import { cube } from './my-module.js';
import { foo, graph } from './my-module.js';

// Likewise, named exports can be imported in groups or individually
```

**Other notes**

- let's revisit the very first example we saw above

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
```

- please note that although, `React` doesn't use braces, and `render` does, `render` is actually a part of `react-dom`.
- therefore it is also possible to import the entire default `react-dom`
  without braces and then use `render`

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

ReactDOM.render()
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider `primitives.js`,

```
export default (a, b) => a + b;
export const sub = (a, b) => a - b;
export const sqr = a => a**2;
```

It can be imported like this,

```
import sum, { sub, sqr } from './primitives';
```

In this case, `sum` is called a "Default Export" and a module may contain a single "Default Export" only.

`sub` and `sqr` are called "Named Export" and a module may contain multiple named exports.

Answer (score 3):

*Curly braces* are used to import `single(specific) property`, whereas the word without braces is `import` `entire object` form that file.

For example,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

Here the word `React` represents to import `entire object` from the file `'react'`.

`{Component}` means we specify to import the `particular property` from the file.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any need to add brackets if you are exporting as default. You can have only default in the module.

Case 1:

```
export default function(num1, num2) {
    return num1 + num2; }
```

Case 2:

```
function sum(num1, num2) {
    return num1 + num2; }

export { sum as default };
```

Case 3:

```
function sum(num1, num2) {
    return num1 + num2; }

export default sum;
```

You can import the default

```
import sum from "./test.js";

console.log(sum(1, 2));
```