# What is the rule of import with curly braces in React / Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I thought the line:

```
import { FETCH_WEATHER } from "../actions/index";
```

means: we don't import the whole object, but import the `obj.FETCH_WEATHER` from the file `../actions/index.js`

One example is, we use

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
```

And it is like, we import from `"react"`, let's call it here as `obj`, and name it `React` in our own file, and `obj.Component`, we name it as `Component` in our own file.

(1) is that true?

(2) in the file `../actions/index.js`, the content is actually:

```
export const FETCH_WEATHER = "FETCH_WEATHER";
```

so there is no object, and no key / value pair to speak of. So what does `import { FETCH_WEATHER }` mean?

Comment: There is an object. The whole module is the object, and exported things are attached to the object as properties and those are accessed.

Comment: I also thought of it this way at first, so I changed it to `import foo from ...` and used `foo. FETCH_WEATHER` but then it gave an error of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'FETCH_WEATHER' of undefined`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [in reactjs, when should I add brackets when import](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41337709/in-reactjs-when-should-i-add-brackets-when-import)

Comment: @太極者無極而生 That's because that's importing the default export, not the module itself. You have no default export so it's undefined

Answer (score 2):

Mozilla Developer Network has a really good documentation on imports in ES6:

[import – JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Basically the imports within the curly brackets are named imports, and must match a named export from the library you're importing from. That can be any object / function / constant that is exported.

Using import without curly brackets imports the default variable / object / function from the library. The default export has `default` keyword as part of the export statement: `export default someVariable`

Answer (score 0):

The module may export one default object and many named items.

It is default module export:

```
const MyClass = (props) => (
  <div/>
)

export default MyClass
```

We can import it like this:

```
import MyClass from "../actions"
```

The curly braces allows to export named items, so if we have such exports:

```
const myConst = "The Text"
const myHelper = (num) => 2*num

export default MyClass
export {myHelper, myConst}
```

We can import its like this:

```
import MyClass, {myHelper, myConst} from "../actions"
```

There is not need to add `index` at path - it is add by default. So write "../actions" enough instead of "../actions/index"

Comment: can you fix `MyObjectHelper, SomeMore` because I don't see them in the file exporting things...

Answer (score 0):

In React, Curly Braces are used to import `single(specific) property`, whereas
the word without braces is `import` `entire object` form that file.

Eg.,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

Here the word `React` represents to import `entire object` from the file `'react'`

`{Component}` means we specify to import the `particular property` from the file.