# What is difference between import createStore and import {createStore} in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

In one of the tutorials on `ReactJS` I just happened to see the following code.

```
import React from 'react';
import {createStore} from 'redux';
```

**Question 1:** So what's the point of {}, I'm sure something must be really interesting and meaningful.

**Question 2:** I come from Python background, so trying to see how similar/different  the importing in ES6 is different from Pythonic way (we don't have {} types in python .

Comment: check this also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795819/when-should-i-use-curly-braces-for-es6-import

Comment: Thanks @MayankShukla Let me explore answer for my question2 in the links you shared.

Comment: You could find this useful as well : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41337709/in-reactjs-when-should-i-add-brackets-when-import/41338672#41338672

Answer (score -1):

In this case, `{}` is a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). It has to do how redux exports createStore function.

comparing it to python it would be 
`from redux import createStore`
vs 
`import react`