# Reactjs - Routing is not work on imported component

Tags: reactjs, import, routes, components, react-router

I'm new to ReactJS and i am developing single page app and I'm just trying to import my components to main component but while clicking on route link it showing blank state or null.

### src\components\Detail.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Detail extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <h2>Detail</h2>
        </div>
        <p>This is the Detail page.</p>;
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Detail;
```

Above module trying to import in App.js for routing

### App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom'
import { Detail } from './components/Detail.js'



const BasicExample = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/detail">Detail</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/topics">Topics</Link></li>
      </ul>

      <hr/>

      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
        <Route path="/detail" component={Detail}/>
      <Route path="/topics" component={Topics}/>
    </div>
  </Router>
)
```

I've not got any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the other components too when you specify a route configuration and `Detail` is a `default export` so you should import `without curly braces`

```
import Home from './components/Home.js'
import About from './components/About.js'
import Detail from './components/Detail.js'
import Topics from './components/Topics.js'
```

Refer **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41337709/in-reactjs-when-should-i-add-brackets-when-import/41338672#41338672)** answer for more info on `named` and `Default export`

Comment: Yes, It work and great see difference between curly bracket while importing module.